# Allow comments to be edited

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)

I've never worked with Greasemonkey so I don't know how it works or if what I'm about to ask is possible, but I had a great idea for a script.

You know how you can post a comment in a hurry, only to later realize that you've posted your comment with a grammatical error?  To correct the error you have to delete your comment and write it all over again (copy+paste if you're really smart).

Why not create a Greasemonkey script that adds an edit button to your comments that allows you to 'edit' your comment by deleting your original and pasting the original in the comment textbox?

Is this a stupid idea? Maybe, but I'm always doing this.

It would be nice if SO supported this automatically (**feature request**).

Comment: shuld jest leaf all errurs to stan in koments as pubic shaym

Comment: dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If comments are edited, a user can change the entire thread with a single edit making every other comment a waste of space and the commenter looks like an idiot. Do you then clutter the UI with revision history for comments.

### My Vote: NO

Comment: well, you can still delete the comment, to the pretty much same effect as you've described (even worse).

Comment: It's actually a much worse affect: User confusion as I discovered, repeatedly, and it is quite jarring. See my writeup at https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4643/14529  (the theory is that someone deleted a comment so that they could correct it after the allowed time-to-edit period has elasped).

Answer (score 4):

If a comment is sufficiently flawed or incomplete and, for fairness, is not referred to by subsequent comments, then it could be re-written and the original deleted by the poster. I do not know if deleted comments are visible to some users but, even so, this seems better than a sequence of partial comments by the same user.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that there is a required 30 seconds between posting comments, and it wouldn't nearly be as functional as editing because if your comment was in the middle of a group of comments, it would appear at the bottom

Comment: The 30 second thing should've been erased once users hit 1000 rep.

Comment: I'm just working with what we got. And what we have, is a 30 second limit. But yeah, the limit should be reduced with rep.

Answer (score 1):

I bump into the same issue over and over again. It just happens all the time, you read you comment and there it is, stupid mistake. It's hard to believe that we don't have that feature done already, Jeff has complained numerous times on podcast that he also makes such mistakes.

To protect flow of discussion I'd say it is enough to make 30 seconds interval during which you can edit your comment and disable edit afterward. 30 seconds should be enough to read 600 chars and you can't post new comments during that time anyway.