# can you edit your own comments

Tags: discussion, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)

are you allowed to edit your comments. .if so how . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If you messed up, just delete your comment and re-write it, though you cannot really do this after someone replies (it'll look funny).

There are other questions concerning it, as well:

[Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)
[Allow comments to be edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12041/allow-comments-to-be-edited)