# Some of my comments in SO are editable while others aren't.. Why?

Tags: support, comments, edits

In StackOverflow, I always wanted the ability to edit my comments. Previously I used to delete them and write a new one.

Suddenly today, I started noticing *edit* link next to my comments. Maybe I didn't notice till now.

But it is there only for some of my comments and not others. Why is it so?

**Edit**

Now, some of those *edit* links are gone. Is the comment editable only for a certain amount of time after writing it?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25831/a-possible-solution-for-editing-comments/33941#33941

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was covered here:

[Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments/33939#33939)

> You can now edit your own comments after you post them, within a 5 minute window.
>
> How do you know a comment has been edited? A little pencil icon will appear next to it. The mouseover title tooltip explains what this pencil icon means, and also provides a count of how many times the comment was edited in that 5 minute window.
>
> Moderators can edit any comments at any time. This action is logged and visible in that moderator's user history to other moderators.