# Comment editing

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, revisions-list

The five minute window helps in fixing some comment mistakes. Comment edits that drastically change the content, alter the flow of the comment thread. But, correcting mistakes in comments after the five minute window requires deletion of the original comment.

My proposal is to allow comment editing after the five minute window, but that the edits must be approved in a manner similar to having edits to questions and answers approved when your reputation isn't high enough.

This will let comments be grammatically corrected, but prevent changing of their meaning.

Here are some references to older pertinent discussions on comment editing. These are from 2009.

- [Proposal to streamline comment editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34046/proposal-to-streamline-comment-editing)
- [Please ditch the five-minute window on comment editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing)

Comment: I rather suspect this won't get implemented. In general, as can be seen by reading through relevant meta posts, comments here are **by design** very much second-class citizens - time and again it has been said that SE wants the focus to remain on questions and answers, and comments can go hang (I paraphrase, of course).

Comment: @AakashM: I got that sense that they were second class citizens. I can also see that making suggestions about features related to comments is good way to burn through rep :-)

Comment: @RichardPovinelli: Personally, I would hate if an edit queue was implemented for comments - it's a waste of time. If you can't say what you need to say in 5 minutes, just post another comment. If you truly can't bear to see a typo you wrote, just delete the comment or don't worry about it. Next thing you know we'd have people editing other people's comments for punctuation, etc. Are you proposing this idea because of a particular "incident"?

Comment: @Madmartigan: No, its not because of a particular incident. After being a member for a couple of months, there were two features (both related to editing comments) I would have found useful. These features would have been most useful when I first started posting. Less so now as I learn more about editing and deleting. Some of which I've learned from comments and answers to my proposed feature :-).

Comment: @Madmartigan: I also don't think editing others comments makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comments are second-class citizens, and that's fine. They don't deserve this type of complexity, and I would consider this type of edit review queue to be a waste of reviewer's time.

Just post a follow-up comment if you want to clear up something you said previously. Breaking the "comment thread" is not a big deal.
If you have more involved discussions around a question or answer, use the chat feature.

Comment: I agree: If your comment contains a typo that doesn't make it clear, you can always add another comment explaining what you really meant. It happened to me, in some occasions, and that is what I did, when deleting the comment was not possible because somebody else added a new comment. Actually, you never know if somebody adds a new comment before you are able to delete yours, and re-add it with the edited text.