# Comment editing time limit

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, user-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please ditch the five-minute window on comment editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing)

Why can a comment only be edited for 5 minutes? If errors cannot be corrected, then the site will remain cluttered. Questions and answers can always be edited and improved. Thus, it would seem reasonable to allow a comment's author to edit comments at any time. However, allowing edits for 30 minutes would allow sufficient time for proofreading and editing.

It would also be nice to have a preview of what the comment it would look like once it is submitted, as with questions and answers.

I do not agree with the [Proposal to streamline comment editing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34046/proposal-to-streamline-comment-editing), but I think increasing the extremely short time limit would be reasonable. It would not be as complex to implement as the above proposal, yet it could solve a lot of problems. As for "A lot can happen on a new, active question in five minutes", many questions have very little activity, even when they are new, and are lucky if something happens every few hours. Compared to this, five minutes is extremely short.

Such a short time limit is inhibiting for people who are not native English speakers and people with disabilities. Accessibility is a real issue, and I believe increasing the time limit would help many users.

What was the philosophy behind the 5 minute editing limit? Could it be changed to allow more time?

Comment: Just delete the comment and rewrite it, or write a new answer (if the comment constitute an answer). I'm not sure how 5 minutes is chosen, but the time period must take into consideration user behavior so that edit to comment can be detected.

Comment: Bad design should not be kept in place because there is a workaround.

Comment: I read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing, and this is not a duplicate. It brings up new points, which were not mentioned in the above article.

Comment: @animuson It was tagged with "Bug", because I felt that it is a bug. Bugs should not be ignored because there is a workaround.

Comment: @ctype.h: The [meta-tag:bug] tag is not for "I don't believe it should work this way," that's what [meta-tag:feature-request] is for. The [meta-tag:bug] tag is for "it says it's *supposed* to work this way, but it's actually working this way." The comment system is working as defined, and you're requesting that it be changed. That's not a bug, by definition.

Comment: @animuson Okay, I see your point, while it may not be a bug, it is an inconsistency.