# Display countdown timer for comment editing

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, time-limit

Sometimes I find something wrong enough with my comments to want to change them. Up until now I have been fine with trying to submit the edit within the 5 minutes, and copy; delete original; then paste into blank comment box, if I get the error about the time limit being reached.

However, today using a tablet (no real keyboard to Ctrl+C/V in a split second), I got a little frustrated with this functionality.

I realise that comments are second class citizens and all, but would anyone else at least find it helpful to have some indication of the time left to edit. This relatively small amount of time for SE to implement this one time code change, may save many people the kind of time I have spent in dealing with this restriction, if they had some idea of the time left, like I obviously have an issue with keeping track of while I am thinking about what to write.

Comment: May be it’s better to completely remove 5 minutes limit? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33997/please-ditch-the-five-minute-window-on-comment-editing

Comment: Sad. I was just about to post the same suggestion and am glad that I did a search first. I really don't understand the reasoning to _not_ implement this, outside of it merely not being a priority. But it would also help in chat rooms for editing those messages. And @MichaelFreidgeim I can there being a reason to have some time limit so that others don't come back years later and change the context (or something like that), but yes, perhaps more than 5 minutes would work. Maybe even just 10 minutes. Will check out the question you linked to. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

As you even said yourself, comments are not classed as important, so you already know why this won't be implemented.

I'll give you my perspective on some points from your question.

---

### We already have a countdown timer

Albeit a count*up* timer.

The time is displayed since *when* the comment was posted ("2 mins ago" etc), and is auto updated - you can watch it incrementing, so you can see how long is left.
When it states "4 mins ago" you have 1 min left to edit.

---

### Comments are not really "content"

Comments don't need nor should they have all sorts of editing options, including a countdown timer.

The 5 minutes is not for allowing us to "manage our content", it is simply to allow a *very basic grace period* to change that stupid typo we spot after submitting, etc.

Because they are not classed as "content" really.

---

### Comments are not worth the bother!

Comments get deleted all the time, without an appeal option, or historical evidence.
They are not just *unimportant* because some users say so, the site setup and comment functionality (or lack of) makes them like that too.

So if you find yourself "often" needing to race against the clock, or even copy/pasting into a *new* comment to update a comment posted more than 5 mins ago, then I *strongly suggest* you are using the comments in the wrong way.

They are just a "quick" note to someone.

> some idea of the time left, like I obviously have an issue with
>   keeping track of while I am thinking about what to write.

and

> edit within the 5 minutes, and copy; delete original; then paste into
>   blank comment box

and

> no real keyboard to Ctrl+C/V in a split second

Sure, we all do things differently, I accept that, but you just shouldn't care so much about comments to even care about the above quoted things!

Comments can be and are deleted as a matter of "bulk clean-up".
If your comment is so "important" perhaps it could be an edit to a question or answer, or a *new* question or answer completely?

I know that is not always the case, but even when not, perhaps you are still making comments more important than they should be.

> may save many people the kind of time I have spent in dealing with
>   this restriction

I doubt there are many people at all who have the issues you face with their comments.
They just post a second comment, or forget about it, because if they forgot something in the first 5 mins, it probably isn't that important.

---

### Examples?

Can you give some examples of comments which are so important that would warrant a copy/paste into a new comment to make improvements?

*Any* comment from anywhere from any user which are "important" and would be a big loss if they were gone.

There are none, which means you are really worrying far too much about your comments.

Comment: The comment countup timer you mention is not displayed while editing... If it were, I wouldn't have asked this question; I find, and have found, comments to be extremely useful in the past, and am sure I will continue to do so. If the information you wish to convey isn't classed as an answer, then comments are all that's left. Often that information is just as valuable as that contained in an answer, _especially_ if there is a mistake in an answer, and the owner of that answer never gets around to changing it; Maybe I am in the minority, but information in any form is important to me.

Comment: I rarely find comments to contain "quick notes"; No doubt my next comment will cause more patronizing response, but I don't agree that everything that gets forgotten after 5 minutes, is unimportant; "Examples?".. Are you serious? My feelings on your demeanor aside, doubt we would agree on comments that are important, but the idea that just because either of us can't think of a situation or one of us find one that the other would consider important, that they don't exist, is just ludicrous. I don't proclaim to know what is in each question, in the over 100+ SE subsites, nor should anyone else.

Comment: @user66001 "*The comment countup timer you mention is not displayed while editing*" No, but that brings me to my point that you are spending too much time on comments. If Comments are that important to you (and sincerely, each to their own :)) then copy/paste the comment text somewhere else while you edit it. Even the answer box is useful, as long as you don't push "submit" on the answer box by mistake (and know that it auto saves a draft now and then, but that can be discarded)

Comment: "*Examples? Are you serious? doubt we would agree on comments that are important*" It wasn't about my trying to change your mind, or you mine, I just have yet to see a comment "ever" which is "important". "*but the idea that just because either of us can't think of a situation or one of us find one that the other would consider important, that they don't exist, is just ludicrous*" I cannot show you all comments to prove there are no important ones, however, if you counter this claim, surely you can find even *one* comment which is "important"? Even from your own comment history?

Comment: @user66001 and James: If James does not see value in it then fine, but I feel that there is a bit of false logic in these explanations: a) not only is the count-up timer not visible (as previously discussed), but even if it was, there's a significant difference between 4:00 since posting and 4:55 since posting when needing 10 - 40 seconds for the edit, and b) saying "you're spending too much time on comments" assumes that a lot of time is needed, but it could merely be 1 - 2 minutes, which isn't a lot, but too much if you only notice at 4:00 since posting, or somewhere around there.