# Why can I edit some comments and not others?

Tags: support, comments, edits, edit-rights

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Some of my comments in SO are editable while others aren’t.. Why?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33952/some-of-my-comments-in-so-are-editable-while-others-arent-why)
>   [A possible solution for editing comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25831/a-possible-solution-for-editing-comments)

I have a little over 9000 reputation over on Stack Overflow, and I've recently been seeing little pencils next to some peoples' comments, indicating they were edited.

Yesterday, for the first time, I saw an `edit` link in a comment of my own, and could have edited it should I have wished to do so.

What's the criterion for being able to edit one's own comments?

Comment: Although answered already, exact duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33952/this-one-right-here

Comment: also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25831/a-possible-solution-for-editing-comments/33941#33941

Comment: and also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments/33939#33939

Comment: I apologize for the dupe. I swear I first searched for similar questions but didn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only edit your own comments, and only if you do so within 5 minutes.  The time when submitting the edit is what matters, not what time you start the edit, too.