# How do I edit my comments?

Tags: support, status-completed, comments, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)

How do I edit a comment that I left on a question?

Comment: Now you do.  >< HO HO HO!  I originally said something vulgar, stupid, and rude there, but its since been edited away with this newfangled comment editing cap.

Comment: @bobobobo aren't you missing a few bobos?

Comment: No.  No I am not, Sam I am.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. You can delete a comment and then add a new one, though.

Edit:

Just for the record, you CAN edit comments now (for a brief period after you submit it).

Comment: Can you preview your comment?

Comment: You can't see what it will look like when it's submitted, no.

Comment: I *totally* and /completely/ <strike>get</strike> **understand** where you're coming from, though, as I have <b>no idea</b> how these words <i>will</i> be formatted.

Comment: I've noticed code blocks in comments - is that just the standard markdown code block, or is that something else?

Comment: @spig, those would be formatted using backticks around the text.

Comment: For that you have to use two `\`` surrounding the code.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new comment with your corrections in it, wait 30 seconds, delete the old one.

(It sure would be nice if the comment restrictions were lightened a little for users with a certain reputation threshold... but then, I dream of a world of ponies and rainbows and waffles too.)

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible. [Yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments).