# What is this clock icon near the voting buttons?

Tags: support, design

On the image from Nick Craver’s [tweet](https://mobile.twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1120306275701678081) where the screenshot of my [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327167/339911) is displayed I noticed a clock icon on the left hand side of the post below the favorite star icon.

> [image: tweet]

What’s the purpose of this icon? Is this the result of some userscript or moderation privilege? Maybe a leak of the site’s future functionality?

A similar icon is used in the iOS-app for Recently Viewed posts:

> [image: iosapp]

Comment: Related: [Can we make the post-issue indicator more tolerant of window size?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188628/can-we-make-the-post-issue-indicator-more-tolerant-of-window-size)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a link to the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) of the post, which used to be shown only to ♦ moderators but since 2020 it's visible for everyone.

[image]

So one of your guesses was right: it's a moderator privilege, which Nick has on all sites.

Answer (score 13):

Just to clarify [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327390): post timelines are **not** ♦-only although the clock-button is ♦-only. They're available for the public albeit there's no visible button under each post (for non-moderators). This is primarily because it's still an [experimental feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view) and the [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447) for adding a visible link to the timeline under every post was [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred).

For what it's worth, you can construct the timeline for any post manually. For example, your question's URL is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32738`, and the corresponding timeline URL is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/32738/timeline` (the page is different from users with different [privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) levels; for instance, mods can view deleted comments and answers in the timeline, whereas non-mod 101 rep users can't).

I personally find the timeline feature quite helpful to track the daily vote totals, and the chronological sequence of answers, edits, close votes and comments even on the sites which I do not moderate. So if you want a timeline button under each post, you could install [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/stack-overflow-extras-sox) and enable the "**Add timeline and revision links to the bottom of each post for quick access to them**" feature. Alternatively, there's [this script](https://stackapps.com/questions/4148/view-post-timeline).

Comment: That "experimental version" was the old one. The one we are using is the one that moderators were using. The timeline version Jeff talks about, doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: FYI, a quick way to access the timeline view without other resources is to right click the edit link, click to open it in a new tab, and then just change "edit" to "timeline" in the page that opens.

Comment: A note for posterity: [The icon with a link to the timeline was made visible to everyone (i.e. not just mods anymore) in January 2020.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/335251)