# Is there a way to edit or delete and reenter comments once they're posted?

Tags: feature-request, support, status-completed, comments, edits

I just posted a comment to someone's answer on SO and accidentally left off the very first backtick, resulting in a really messed up looking comment. Of course I couldn't see the result of that omission until I posted it and by then it was too late to fix it. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments

Comment: Why no link to the post?

Comment: Thanks guys for a quick fix. This site is amazing! I would post a link but it's lost in the clouds and I don't even remember the subject now. (would upvote but don't have the rep here yet.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Outside the 5 minute comment editing courtesy window**, only by manually re-entering it; note:

- destroys the ordering if somebody has commented on your comment
- copy/paste (from the existing comment on screen) doesn't preserve formatting

I make typos, so I kinda got into the habit of "copy" *before* posting, so if I noticing a formatting goof I can fix it by deleting, and re-adding ("paste").

Comment: good habit to get into.  i've gotten as far as the "proofread again after posting" step, just in case, but i haven't trained myself to copy the text before posting.  unfortunately this means i get to recreate any special formatting by hand.  (on the plus side, that usually eats up enough time that i'm well beyond the 30-sec-wait-between-comments timeout.)

Answer (score 0):

You can now edit your own comments after you post them, within a 5 minute window.

How do you know a comment has been edited? A little pencil icon will appear next to it. The mouseover title tooltip explains what this pencil icon means, and also provides a count of how many times the comment was edited in that 5 minute window.

Moderators can edit any comments at any time. This action is logged and visible in that moderator's user history to other moderators.