# Love the new edit feature on comments

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)

Sure beats copy/paste/edit/submit/delete.

Anything I should know about it?  Is there a time-limit on edits?

Answer (score 3):

All kudos go to [Jarrod](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00002/).

Info on the feature is in the [feature-request] question:

[Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)

Comment: I take no responsibility for any bugs, only said kudos ;-)