# Why do some comments have a "pencil icon"?

Tags: support, comments, comment-edits

Why do some comments have a "pencil" icon at the end.

When does it happen, and what does it mean?

> [image]

Comment: Testing comment editing... EDIT: Added edit #1 EDIT: Added edit #2

Comment: edited a lots of times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because they were edited within 5 minutes of their creation. See [**Should we be allowed to edit comments?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments)

Answer (score 6):

It means that someone edited the comment. You can edit comments up to 5 minutes from the time you posted it. If you hover over the pencil it even tells you why it's there!

[image: hover to see what the pencil means]

Answer (score 1):

It's to signify the editing of a comment.

If you hover over the pencil image, it'll say it has been edited X times. I'll give you an example.

Comment: if you hover over the **pencil**, not comment