# Why can't I edit my own comments on my own question more than two times?

Tags: support, comment-edits

I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450941/coordinate-transformation-in-svg-inside-firefox-with-scrollbars), got an answer, commented one time (comment #1), edited that comment twice, then added a new different comment (comment #2), deleted comment #2, and then could no longer edit comment #1. Why?

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Comment 1 must have just fallen out of the grace period for editing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only get a five-minute window to edit comments. See [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments/33939#33939).

There is no actual limit on the *number* of edits per se. I've edited my comments as many as four or five times to try to get the formatting right.

Comment: Aren't comment edits rate limited? Everything else is, I'd be surprised to find out that they aren't. If they are, that, plus the 5 minute window, would put an upper bound on the number of possible edits....and after a bit of experimenting, it turns out that they are...so you can only make 60 edits, 300s/5s/edit = 60 edits.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I don't think so. But I'm going to try it out. Three edits in 30 seconds ought to do it, maybe? Or six in 45 seconds? Nope, apparently not.

Comment: @mmyers - I got rate limited.  The message indicated a 5 second window per edit.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Is it 5 seconds per edit or (total edits / 5 seconds)? I.e., if you wait for a minute and then start editing feverishly, does it limit you? (I can't even get the edit window to open and close in five seconds.)

Comment: @mmyers -- appears to be 5/sec per edit. The message is "You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds" -- I did a series of edit/save/edit/save without actually making changes until I got the warning.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Still can't reproduce it. Perhaps that rate limit does not apply to moderators? I know the comment upvoting limits still apply, but the comment deleting limits don't.

Comment: @mmyers - I wish I was special. :-(

Comment: @tvanfosson: Can you try it again? Tim Post couldn't reproduce it, and he's not a moderator on this site.

Comment: @mmyers - sure, I'll screen capture this time: see http://tinypic.com/r/otl0js/4

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the copy/delete/paste (& edit) method to update a comment, even outside the 5 minute edit window.

Comment: Although it is a little awkward when someone's responded in the meantime.

Comment: @mmyers - true, but sometimes fixing that glaring spelling error that makes you look like an idiot is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to edit comments is on a timer. You can only edit your comments within a five minute time frame. Five minutes give you enough time to fix those "oops, I made a typo" moments. But it makes it less likely that people will change the *content* their comments after the fact.