# Where can I find, Religion Exchange, Christian Exchange, or Bible Exchange?

Tags: feature-request, site-proposal

I love Stack Exchange so much and have learned so much from it. I'm looking for a place to discuss the Bible. Is there an SE site about this yet? I've noticed atheism SE, but a Religion Exchange or Judeochristian Exchange or Bible Exchange would be nice.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity

Comment: Quick note: Stack Exchange isn't really a great platform for *discussion* sites. I rather suspect this will prove troublesome to open-ended "fan sites" like Atheism or the proposed Christianity... [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics) looks to be more along the lines of a focused Q&A site, I recommend looking over the example questions posted there and throwing your support behind it if it meets your needs.

Comment: @Shog makes a good point. I think [mi.yodeya.com](http://mi.yodeya.com) (About jewish life and learning) is an example how a Stack Exchange site on a religious topic can work, and work well

Comment: Shog, yes I totally see your point. I'm kind of an optimist though.but yes I see that biblical hermeneutics might actually work in this context. It would be great to see answers fro

Comment: From different backgrounds. Baptist answers and reformed answers etc.

Comment: @Josh: Perhaps you aren't aware that you can [edit your comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments/33939#33939)?

Comment: Thanks Raven. I know I can edit them. I should have been less lazy. I've been using SO for a while now :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I count at least three strong proposals with a decidedly christian background on in the "culture" category: http://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/3/culture

- [Biblical hermeneutics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1817/biblical-hermeneutics)
- [Christianity](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity)
- [Christian Worship Leading and Service Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2328/christian-worship-leading-and-service-design)

Comment: Old answer poke: Christianity SE and Biblical Hermenuetics SE are both in beta now.

Comment: Old comment poke: Christianity graduated. :-)