# I can not edit my own comment which is 20 minutes old

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, grace-period

I can not Edit my comment which was posted 20 minutes ago. I can only delete it.

If I add a new comment I can delete or edit it.

Is this a bug or feature? I don't see why someone should not be able to edit his/her own comments.

I usually double check my posts before I put a comment or an answer but I would like to correct a possible typo to keep the posts clean.

Comment: You have a window of, I think, 5 minutes to edit your comments.

Comment: What if you come next day and you see a typo? Why not keep the posts clean? If this is a feature is this really hard to implement?

Comment: @joran Didn't see your comment, but you beat me to it.

Comment: Yes I want to know why this not implemented?

Comment: @SNash I think it all stems from the general philosophical position that comments are "second class content". They are not intended to be permanent, nor should they include information vital to a question/answer.

Comment: I disagree with above, again the question is what's wrong with keeping the posts clean?

Comment: It would make comments more important than they really are @JoeTatavaran. And, without a maintained edit history, it would mean one could edit their comments into something they didn't initially say, with all kinds of consequences. Once again, solving that would mean making comments far more important than they should be and are.

Comment: Ok above makes more sense. But then doesn't same thing apply to questions also. someone can completely change their questions by editing.

Comment: Yep, and there we have an edit history, the ability to roll back edits, etc. Hence the "if we do this for comments, it would make them much more important that we want them to be".

Comment: I think you're not catching on to the idea that the site has taken the position that comments are _less important_ than questions and answers. That's why they are treated differently.

Comment: Questions and answers are taken "out of time", editing them can only be a good thing as they're not supposed to have any order. On the other hand comments are often replys to each other, order is critical, the ability to edit them would allow dangerous things. Imagine replying "I agree" to a comment that could be edited to be anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a feature. You can only edit your comment [for five minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33939/218097) after you post it, according to Jeff Atwood:

> You can now edit your own comments after you post them, within a 5 minute window.
>
> How do you know a comment has been edited? A little pencil icon will appear next to it. The mouseover title tooltip explains what this pencil icon means, and also provides a count of how many times the comment was edited in that 5 minute window.
>
> Moderators can edit any comments at any time. This action is logged and visible in that moderator's user history to other moderators.

Comment: Looks like the edit count isn't there anymore.

Comment: @Juhana I still see the edit count it if I edit a comment more than once. Try it on this comment.

Comment: Oh I see, it doesn't explicitly say that it's been edited only once.