# Edit button displaying on different comment

Tags: support, comments, comment-edits

I commented on a question : [Escaping in base64 encode php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22111193/escaping-in-base64-encode-php?noredirect=1)

I needed to edit it, but there is no **edit** button aside to the comment. User @pat mentioned me in the next comment and I have the edit button (not clickable) on his (pat) comment :

> [image]

Comment: If you mean the little pencil, it **means** that a comment was edited, nothing more.

Comment: @Oded Thanks. I confued it with the dit button, So why can't I edit my own comment ? There is no edit button

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/459/should-we-be-allowed-to-edit-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your own comments any number of times for first five minutes only after posting the comment. After that you can not edit the comment. And your comment is more than 5 minutes old that's why the "edit" link is not there.

There reason @pat can see "edit" link even after 5 minutes is that he has not refreshed the page after posting that comment.