# Modifying comments long after 5 minute deadline

Tags: support, comments, flags, moderation

I just flagged 3 comments. One got deleted, one - to the best of my memory - got modified to something I'd be less inclined to flag. Modification happened 4 days after the comment was written.

Can mods modify (not just delete) comments of other users? Can users with enough privilege do that with their own comments?

Comment: Yes, moderators can edit comments of other users. No, there's no such privilege. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33939/260312

Comment: From the linked dupe: "♦ moderators can edit or delete any comment".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [diamond moderators can edit comments without a deadline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/33939/245360).

Only diamond moderators can do this; it is not a reputation privilege.

Comment: How is such moderator privilege justified given that the said user can't revert/adjust the edit? Something that one might not agree with becomes associated with that user's name. Deletion I understand, editing - not so much.

Comment: @A.S. Moderators are supposed to be trustworthy. They can suspend and even delete accounts, so editing comments should not be an issue. Also, you can still delete your comment after a moderator has edited it.

Comment: It's not a question of trustworthiness but of mind-reading. If the edit is minor, it's not necessary, if the edit is major, the deletion is more appropriate. Majorly edited comments (with no revision history available/no time-stamp of the latest edit) remove appropriate context from comments that follow (one can infer a deletion from a gap in the flow but not an unmarked late edit).

Comment: @A.S. feel free to flag the comment again if it bothers you so much.

Comment: @Shadow As I mentioned in the OP, it doesn't. What bothers me is that there is no track-record (that is visible to me) of these late edits. The time-stamp on the comment should be updated when modified late by the mod. I had to do a triple-take to make sure I wasn't imagining changes. A time-stamp would set things straight.

Comment: @A.S. comments are minor. There is a pencil icon when the comment is edited, and moderators can probably see the revisions. All in all, really can't see any problem here.

Comment: @Shadow If comments are that minor, they should not be modified by a mod trying to mindread the author. Comments already track the last revision time and number of revisions. Why shouldn't moderator's actions be a part of this tracking?

Comment: @A.S. well, feel free to start new feature requests, one asking to remove the moderators ability to edit comments, and one to publicly record such edits, as long as it's allowed.