# Can't Edit Own Comment

Tags: support, comments, edits

I can't edit my own comments on my own questions and answers.
I can still delete and add a comment, so if I really wanted to, I could copy my previous comment, add a comment, paste it in, make changes, and delete the old comment.
This happens on all communities that I am on, regardless of the community. One example:

[image: Comment with remove button]

But there is no edit button. This is my own comment on an answer to my question. On another community:

[image]

Alas, no edit button, even though there is a delete button. I could copy the comment, delete the comment, add a comment, paste it in, and make changes. As of writing, I have < 50 reputation on all communities. If it is not currently possible to edit comments, please add the feature-request tag to this question, instead of down-voting, deleting or closing this question.

Comment: You can only edit your own comments for five minutes.  See [Should we be allowed to edit comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/459/300411)