# Please change linking algorithm in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments

When somebody posts a URL in the comments, it is automatically cleaned up and turned into a link. This is an excellent feature, but the system does not allow some symbols in URLs. For example, I've added a comment to this question consisting entirely of the text

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphey's_Law
```

but when you try to click on the link, you get taken to the page `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphey`, which is the **wrong page**.

Is there some reason `'` is assumed not to be in URLs? Can we change the comment link algorithm to allow `'`s?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphey's_Law

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphey%27s_Law

Comment: If I've understood random's comment to Jeff's answer correctly, this behavior is completely standard. Is it possible to tell my browser to automatically encode the URL in my URL bar so that I can just copy and paste?

Comment: What about http://☃.net and http://www.☃.net ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So encode the ' then

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphey%27s_Law

Comment: That's a fine workaround, but it would be really nice if I could just paste the URL in as it appears at the top of my browser. Is there some reason not to allow that?

Comment: Actually, I'm being a bit dodgy. The reason I want this feature-request implemented is because I have an SE site and I don't want my users to have to know how to encode `'`s. But Michael Pryor has said that if a feature-request pertains to the S[OFU] sites as well as SE sites, he'd rather wait for you to implement it.

Comment: Quotes are reserved characters: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its related to WMD, so, I just tried to reverse-engineer some of its js.

basically, adding `'` to this line

```
var E=/^(<a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)']+)"(\stitle="[^"<>]+")?\s?>|<\/a>)$/i;
```

and this line

```
G=G.replace(/(^|\s)(https?|ftp)(:\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|\[\]\(\)!:,\.;']*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|\[\]])($|\W)/gi,"$1<$2$3>$4");
```

and removing `'` from `[^'">\s]` from this line

```
G=G.replace(/<((https?|ftp):[^">\s]+)>/gi,'<a href="$1">$1</a>');
```

works here for `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphey's_Law`

But, better replace `'` to `%27` in background, because its smells like SQLi :D

<sub>**PS**: There is accepted answer already, but Jeff just bumped it, so looks like he might considering this again.</sub>

Comment: Great, please add ☃ as well ;-)

Comment: Heh, thats need to judge by Jeff :D

Comment: this has nothing to do with WMD, it is related to URLs in comments per the title.. I retagged it to help.

Comment: Jeff, how about in normal question and answer?, now, url with `'` does not work too.