# How can I format only part of a word in a comment?

Tags: discussion, comments

Since comments gained the ability of some very limited formatting that's also a source of frustration involved. The syntax is, while *similar* to the main post syntax, still different enough that you stumble over the discrepancies every now and then.

Something like `*foo*-bar` works in normal posts but not in comments.

Case in point here: *How the hell does the parser work?*

Or rather: What do I need to do to the string to work? Adding a space after the interior `*` *does* work. But that's sort of a non-solution. Adding U+200B in there does *not* work (would have been too easy, I presume).

**ETA:** Ok, in the comments I've been doing some testing. It appears that everything that's a space seems to work (suggests `\s` is used somewhere). Since the zero-width space isn't a space it doesn't work. While I used `foo-bar` as a test string I also sometimes wanted to emphasize part of a non-hyphenated word, something like `*un*foo` (which works in Markdown, even though it doesn't appear to work in the JS preview. However, I would have expected the hyphen-minus at least to count as a delimiter. Looks like the hair space is the best option so far.

Comment: *foo* -bar U+2008 (too long)

Comment: *foo* -bar U+2009 (noticeable, but might be ok for most people)

Comment: *foo* -bar U+200A (nigh-invisible; well, it's a hair space after all; might be that it only seem to work for italic, though) – **foo** -bar, `foo` bar (no, seems ok; code formatting adds space anyway)

Comment: *foo*​-bar U+200B (would have been nice)

Comment: *foo*‌-bar U+200C (not the right tool for the job, but maybe ... nope)

Comment: *foo*‍-bar U+200D (still not the right tool, but one can hope ... nope)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33578/can-we-have-a-markdown-help-button-for-comments

Comment: Jon: not exactly, though. The question is about showing the features that are avilable in comments. I think a full-page explanation on why comment markup is inconsistent with the normal markup (even with the parts that look similar) might be too much.

Comment: @Johannes: I'm just saying that if the MarkDown behaviour for comments is fully documented somewhere, it would cut down on a lot of confusion about issues that come up over and over again.

Comment: @Jon: an, true that. It's not Markdown, though, as the backslashes-are-markup-suddenly-too issue doesn't exist in the normal post syntax (which uses Markdown). It's more like an extended subset. Akin to browser CSS support or so :-)

Answer (score 2):

Intra word styling is not supported in comments.

Your workarounds using thin word separators work, and is likely to be the only thing you can do to get the effect.

Comment: Is there something like an official list of functional differences between Markdown and the sorta-like-Markdown-but-totally-different comment formatting? Not a list of features vs. features but differences between similar-looking features. Like that backslashes are markup too now and stuff like that.