# Too many people (even long time members) not using the "@"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, notifications, behavior

I keep seeing the following scenario:

1. John Doe posts a question.
2. The question is either not clear enough or missing some code.
3. People post comments asking to clarify and/or post his code.
4. The OP post comment back or edit his code and comment about it, but put no @namehere in the comment so those who commented never see it and the poor OP get no help.

Personally if I post comment and not answer I usually add the question to my favorites thus "follow" it to see such comments, but looks like I'm the only one who is doing this.

What can we do to encourage people to use the "@" more? It's for the good of the whole community, as people respond to comment, expecting reply but get none because nobody was notified.

Comment: Does it mean that if I write '@FullUserName: comment' he will be notificated through the inbox?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71903/add-a-comment-syntax-help-when-writing-a-comment

Comment: Yep that's the goal of the `@`.. :)

Comment: @Ladislav sorry I repeated the same mistake I'm talking about, leaving comment on your comment without notifying you.. :-/

Comment: @Oak related yes but not duplicate, as my intention here is pure discussion to discuss ways to improve the current situation.. that discussion might result in feature requests. :-)

Comment: Omg another feature I didn't know about ...

Comment: @Ladislav yep, that's exactly my point in "even long time members". By the way, you don't have to write the full name, partial name is enough (until the first non-letter character e.g. `Shadow` or `Ladislav`)

Comment: What happens if two users "Ladislav A" and "Ladislav B" participate in conversation and I type only @Ladislav?

Comment: Related: [Using the comment "pro tip" increases the risk of not getting notified about responses by new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64501/using-the-comment-pro-tip-increases-the-risk-of-not-getting-notified-about-resp) - my response to this would be the same. We can't teach this by demonstration as there are a lot of rules to it. New users need to be explicitly taught this. I can't think of much that will work besides just spreading a link to the rules as often as possible.

Comment: (Shadow, as you're the author of this post I cannot prove it to you, but 3 characters is enough. All nifty details at [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), @Lad.)

Comment: @Arj thanks that's new "even" for me. But how can you send notification to more than one person? I saw once something like `@name1 AND name2` is this the way?

Comment: No, you can't send notifications to more than one person. Period. Any syntax you see that looks like it does not work. Only the first mention in your comment will work.

Comment: @Grace thanks - so the only way is to write separate comment for each person I want to notify?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can read more in the link that @Arjan already provided.

Comment: @Lad, using @LadislavA or @LadislavB (without the whitespace) would do the trick if you need to be more specific.

Comment: @Chris don't you get access to moderation tools at 10K reputation?

Comment: @Shadow - yes, but you need to be a diamond moderator to be able to edit your own comments outside the 5 minute post-post window.

Comment: @Ladislav - the last mentioned would get the notification as it works in reverse chronological order.

Comment: @Arjan hmm.. so when I have `@name:` the notification won't work? Couldn't figure this out from the rules. :/

Comment: Okay, `@arjan:` works just fine.

Comment: @Arjan: what about members with less than 3 letters in their display name (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/users/272756/c) - they will never get any notifications from other members?

Comment: Users with less than 3 characters in their username don't get notified, nor [get warned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65154/disallow-usernames-that-cannot-be-replied-to) as far as I know, @Shadow. (Well, they *will* get notified if they are the author of a question or answer, but not when explicitly using the `@reply` syntax.)

Comment: @Arjan A new system was added that restricts users from having display names shorter than 3 characters. The only people who have it are those who haven't changed their names since then. So going forward, that's not going to be a problem that much. The advancing issue is that people like Yi Jiang will still get addressed as @Yi Jiang, which will miss.

Comment: Ah, @Grace, [you're right](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45241/prevent-or-at-least-notify-about-display-names-shorter-than-3-chars/50693#50693)! I'll flag [Disallow usernames that cannot be @replied to](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65154/disallow-usernames-that-cannot-be-replied-to) to get `status-completed` then.

Comment: @Arjan 50% of the time my `@` symbol disappears and takes the username with it. It drives me insane b/c ppl like you judge me for it.

Comment: @puk it disappears because the person you refer to will always get notification by being the post author. Just write the name without `@`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks. It was killing me b/c there's literally nowhere I could find out why. I wish there was a wiki for first time users (is there one?)

Comment: @puk Well, the "help" link to the right show text saying "The post author will always be notified of your comment. **To also notify a previous commenter**, mention their user name" - the part in bold hints about what happens but you're right, it never says something will be automatically removed.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that's what I was looking for. For some reason I never saw the `help` link. I wonder if anyone else has been tricked by this disappearing `@` sign

Comment: @puk Many were tricked, baffled and frustrated by this - some asked to cancel this but to no avail. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation). :-)

Comment: @puk, as for judging folks: where am I judging people here? Something about pot and kettle comes to mind.

Comment: @Arjan I didn't mean an inquisition. Every once in a while ppl kept pointing out that I should use `@`, but I had given up b/c to me it seemed unreliable

Comment: @puk they meant you should use it when addressing people other than the post author - guess you realize it by now though? :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there existed a `add reply` button with every comment, similar to the `upvote comment` and `flag comment` buttons, this could be more or less avoided.

If the `add reply` button is clicked the add comment field should be opened but would already contain: "@FullUserName: ". This would also remove the risk of spelling errors of the user name.

Comment: I think there is a greasemonkey script for this

Comment: @Kop There is, it's listed in [another answer to this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74516/too-many-people-even-long-time-members-not-using-the/74528#74528).

Comment: @Kop still, would be nice to have it as integral part of the site. :)

Comment: I don't use greasemonkey. So a 'Reply' button would be very useful.

Comment: reply button will always be denied with extreme prejudice. But there are greasemonkey scripts.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Why will it be denied with extreme prejudice?

Comment: I for one won't deny reply button.. IMO that's the best suggestion that will have the best effect in the end of the day.

Answer (score 4):

Note that **you only need to use @ when you are addressing someone *other than the person who wrote the post***.

Post owners are always notified of comments on their questions and answers. Therefore, the following extremely common scenarios work just fine, no @name required:

- posting a comment on a question: question owner always notified
- posting a comment on an answer: answer owner is always notified

So I think you misunderstand a bit how @ notifications work; they are largely for communication between two random commenters, not at all for communication between question owner and answerers.

edit: click the help link under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options, including a brief @reply explanation.

[image: commenting help]

Additionally, per:

[Micro-refinement to notifications for comments of others posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts)

> If a user comments on their own post and there is only one person who has previously commented, then that person should be notified when the author comments even if '@user' is not specified.

Comment: Nope, this time I didn't misunderstand.. see this question for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642344/show-content-with-fancybox-like-a-javascript-alert - the OP wasn't clear in his question, I asked for clarification and he posted comment on my comment.... if I wasn't following the question I would never know he posted that comment.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: That is indeed the most common scenario where it breaks down. A new user asks a question, someone asks for a clarification in a comment, the new user types a new comment... and nobody gets notified. Because the first comment doesn't need an `@` to reach the new user, many times it is left off and the new user doesn't see a good example of how they should reply. A reply button or a warning "nobody will get a notification unless you write `@name`" could work here.

Answer (score 3):

For those interested, there is a greasemonkey user script that adds a “Reply” link (as an arrow: ↵) after every comment. It is available [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments).