# Add ability to reply to specific comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies

Sometimes someone may post more than one comment on a post. If I am referring to one of their older comments it is hard to tell which one I am responding to, without going into details in the comment ("Regarding your comment on January 21st, [...]").

It would be nice to add a chat-like reply feature, where your comment's @ mention is replaced with a link to a specific comment, while still appearing as an @ mention, but with a reply symbol in front of it. Clicking on the mention would highlight the replied-to comment.

Here is a screenshot of something similar in chat:

[image: Image showing reply ability in chat]

Comment: You mean [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4798/lets-make-it-easier-to-reply-within-comments)?

Comment: @PatrickHofman not really. That was posted in 2009 and is about @ mentions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add "Reply" link to comment that pre-populates comment box with @username](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74778/add-reply-link-to-comment-that-pre-populates-comment-box-with-username)

Comment: If you are using comments as chat, the solution is to stop using comments as chat, not to add chat features to comments.

Comment: @Mithrandir no, that would just pre-populate the comment and is a quality of life thing.

Comment: @zaq This is not about using comments as chat. Suppose PatrickHofman replied to this comment. If I wanted to respond to his first comment, I would have to either explain this in the comment, or I would just be able to click a reply button.