# Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

I just posted a comment beginning with `@username`, and my `@username` part of the comment disappeared (it was the first word in the comment).

Is there a lolcat inside the Stack Exchange database nomming on notifications? May I suggest you feed it?

[image: lolcats always get peoples attention]

<sub>P.S. I'm guessing this is a brand spanking new feature, but I can see this coming up a lot</sub>

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, this is new.

@lerting the post owner in a comment is not necessary.  If comments are only between you and the post-owner, and nobody else is commenting, then an @lert to the post owner at the beginning of a comment will be removed.

Comment: I thought there was a canonical post by Jeff which explains how this is the greatest thing ever and not at all likely to confuse people, but I can't find it, so I'm registering it here: [yet another user confused by this useless feature](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9664/how-do-you-configure-inputrc-so-altup-has-the-effect-of-cd/9677#comment60686_9677).

Comment: @Gilles - my question about something similar was closed - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148389/username-disappears-in-comment#comment426310_148389 - However, I am still confused by this. In this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588249/webcryptoapi-secure-or-not - I tried to add 'at'tntu while replying to tntu's comment but it disappeared. tntu is not post owner - so It shouldn't have disappeared, right?

Comment: It is misleading to suddenly have your @tag vanish in only some cases. I have been using SO for a while, was really confused by this feature and then i had to search for like five minutes before i finally stumbled this (above) question and explanation. At any rate this is an inconsistent usability aspect and at the very least should have SOME indication about what happened IMHO.

Comment: I don't really like this feature. `@name` can be useful if you want to make it clear that you're responding to another comment and not commenting on the post. Also, if a user writes `@name`, there is a reason and so it should not be removed.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff You said post owner. However, does it also work for answerers or other commenters as well?

Comment: Funny, just tried to post a comment under the OP, so that it would contain <15 characters when stripped of the @lert... and guess what? The character counter at the bottom was silent, but _Add comment_ button gave an error that the comment must be at least 15 characters in length. Very confusing for an unaware user.