# What happened to @username in comments?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)

I just added a comment in response to someone else's comment and found the @username stripped out of the comment. What gives? I thought this was useful when determining which comments were in response to which. Also, doesn't this alert the other user that he/she's been replied to?