# Automatic removal of @username behaves incorrectly with changed user names

Tags: support, status-completed

The automatic removal of the `@username` greeting in comments (see [Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)) behaves incorrectly in the case of changed user names:
The post [How to get straight quotation marks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7735/how-to-get-straight-quotation-marks/7738#7738) was written by a user called `xport_is_sleeping`, which is the name used in the first comment (`@xport_is_sleeping`). The user has since changed their name to just `xport`. With the automatic removal of `@username`, the comment now starts with `_is_sleeping`, which can be confusing for users who don't know the older user name.

Comment: just to be clear, that's an artifact of the one time manual retroactive removal network wide, not an issue with the current code for new comments.

Comment: @Jeff: Thanks for fixing this so quickly, but isn't it a sign that something is wrong with the process of changing a user name? When `xport_is_sleeping` changed their name to `xport`, shouldn't all instances of their user name have been changed? So this problem could be relevant to more cases than the one I linked to.

Comment: different issue though; if you were to change your name from "Jake" to "super-mega-bobulator" right this second, every old @username text eplies in comments would remain as-is.. all the more reason to encourage people not to use that @username unless they HAVE to. (that is, they are speaking to other commenters and not to the post owner.) For example in the comment you left, putting my name in was not necessary, because we can infer.. you obviously were talking to me, not yourself, yes? :)

Comment: Ah, this has been discussed in such breadth already. Personally, I liked being able to distinguish between a comment directed at the poster, and one directed at people who want to use a solution given in an answer (which is not so relevant on the Meta pages, but quite so on the "real" ones). I feel like this new feature makes the wrong assumption that first comments to an answer are only used for communicating directly with the poster, which is simply not true.

Comment: Just out of interest: Why did you retag the question from `bug` to `support`? According to the tag wiki, `bug` "...indicates a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error.", while `support` "...indicates a request for assistance with one of the site's features.". Wasn't the described problem due to an incorrect behaviour of the one time `@alert` excision (a "programming error")?

Comment: @Jeff: Sorry, final thing: I'm confused now about whether I need to use @lerts in a discussion with only one other person on my own post. Since only the @alert with the username of the post owner gets removed because it is redundant, I assume that @lerting the other person is not redundant. However, you said "For example in the comment you left, putting my name in was not necessary, because we can infer". Did you get notified of my comments that didn't start with @Jeff?

Comment: yep I did. Think about it this way: were you talking to yourself in that comment? Who else *could* you have been taking to? If the answer is "obviously the one other person talking in comments" then you have your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update PostComments
set Text = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(Text, '_is_sleeping', '')))
where Text like '_is_sleeping%'

4 row(s) affected
```

And just for good measure...

```
update PostComments
set Text = LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(Text, '@xport_is_sleeping', '@xport')))
where Text like '%@xport_is_sleeping%'

26 row(s) affected
```