# Editing comment doesn't work when only a reference to user is added

Tags: support, comments, notifications, comment-replies, comment-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)

It happened to me twice already that I forgot to put an `@author` in my comment to notify the answerer of my comment. When I edit my comment to put the`@author` in front of my comment and pushed the "Save Edit" button, the `@author` didn't appear. When I changed something else in my comment and put the `@author` in front, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `@usernmame` notification is removed if the comment is directed at the owner of the post being commented on as this person *always* gets notifications of comments.

So for example if I were to add a comment on your question starting with `@Torsten` it would be redundant as you would be notified by default.

If you want to make it clear that you are addressing the author of the post just remove the `@`.