# @author alert removal gets confused by a non-ASCII character

Tags: bug, status-completed, comment-replies, automatic-edits

Notice the comments in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/combinatorial-proof-that-binomial-coefficients-are-given-by-alternating-sums-of-s/44763#44763) for [Combinatorial proof that binomial coefficients are given by alternating sums of squares?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44759/combinatorial-proof-that-binomial-coefficients-are-given-by-alternating-sums-of-s/) Two of the comments begin with the funny-looking string "š:". The author of the answer is Luboš Motl.

What I think happened is that the comments originally began "@Luboš:", before the new feature was introduced to [automatically remove @user alerts to the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation), but apparently that feature got confused when faced with the "š" in "Luboš".

I assume this is a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an issue with the one-time historical fixup we ran, not the current removal code.

I'll check elsewhere for instances of this, but it should be rare; just flag them for moderator attention any site you seem them on.