# Can we have a notification when our comment is changed?

Tags: discussion, comments, design

Just to chime in with an idea to move forwards on the heated issue raised in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation) Question, rather than try to reverse the issue.

Sometimes a comment is modified by the system, removing a @user: in the begining of the post. This is apparently because the user will be notified in any case.

In such an event, can there be a nice yellow notice box notifying the user that their post has been changed?
This will allow the comment-poster to modify their post, by omitting the @ symbol for example, to specify to whom the comment is written, but without invoking `s/@[a-z]+://` .

Comment: Notice boxes are a very expensive UI item from a cognitive standpoint; they are an interruption, and it's going to be pretty annoying for most users. Are you sure you don't want to just re-check your own comment to see if the @user remains intact?

Comment: I think that it is even more confusing when you edit the comment, put in the @user and find it disappears without explanation when you hit add comment (or whatever). if you like, the box can appear for a finite number of times for each user.

Comment: Also, I think that changing my text is very expensive from a cognitive stand-point: if I do not understand whats going on, I have to start looking at meta and asking questions and doubting my sanity...I'd much rather have a box remind me.