# Help with the "@person" feature?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

When I respond to a question or answer, sometimes the sites ignore my `@poster` call out.

I'll type:

> @Bob - I'd use a left-handed #8 semi-widget

but what gets posted is

> I'd use a left-handed #8 semi-widget

In these cases, the helper popup doesn't come up either.  It's as if I'm not allowed to refer to a previous poster, and I don't know why.

Comment: Was this on Bob's post?  If so they're notified anyway so it doesn't allow you to do it manually :)

Comment: @dennis - Thanks.  Since I didn't know what they were called, I couldn't search on them.  I'll go read now.

Answer (score 2):

From [How do comment @replies work? - Accepted Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020):

> ​10. The first author of the question or answer will always be notified of any new comment. There is no need to use *@name* to notify them. (You may still use it for clarity, if needed; however if only you and the author have been commenting on the post so far, the *@name* will be [automatically removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.)