# @username disappears in comment.

Tags: support, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Eeeeek - what happened to my @ salutation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation)

In Stack Overflow, when I try to add @username in comments to reply to a particular user's comments, the @username disappears when I click on <kbd>Add Comment</kbd>. How do I actually put @username - I know it works because I have seen other users use it.

Comment: Is the person you try to reply to the OP of the post? If so, that's entirely normal. They will be notified anyway.

Comment: @Bart In this comment if I want to add your name - will it work? Update: It did work. However - in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588249/webcryptoapi-secure-or-not - I tried to add 'at'tntu while replying to tntu's comment but it disappeared.

Comment: Because he wrote the answer you tried to add a comment to. He will be notified anyway.

Comment: Note that if there is already comment from a different user then it won't disappear. It will also not disappear if added in the middle of the comment.