# Minimum comment length counter thinks @username is part of comment length

Tags: bug, comments, character-limit

If I try to post a comment like this:

`@asdf won't work`

(where asdf is the OP, and [no one else has commented on the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97099/160599))

The comment length counter reports:

`584 characters left`

But it will not be able to post. A red pop-up will appear saying that comments must be more than 15 characters in length. The reason seems to be that @username is not considered part of the comment length (and rightfully so), but the counter is blissfully unaware of this.

Could it be edited so that instead it will correctly say

`4 more to go...`

?

Comment: `@asdf` has to be a valid reply target, by the way for anyone trying to reproduce this.

Comment: @hammar testing

Comment: ^ Looks like it worked for me, did I miss something?

Comment: @Kevin: It's only misleading when the at-notify gets *stripped*, likely due to it being a reply to the OP where the at-notify isn't necessary.

Comment: @patashu op too

Comment: @animuson ^ worked with the OP too. Wonder if there's a browser thing somewhere

Comment: Might only trigger [when the @reply gets auto-removed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97099/160599). In that case, the rules are complex enough that I see why the counter doesn't work. Still, I'd support a feature-request to never include the `@reply` in the minimum, which would make the logic simple enough for the counter.

Comment: @Kevin: It only does that when it's a conversation strictly between the OP and you. Since it's only the two of you, there's no reason to have it there. Once other people join the comment conversation, then at-replies never get stripped, so you can tell who the comment is directed at.

Comment: @animuson I see, I've clarified that in the post