# Tagging people in replies doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

I experienced some days ago in SO that whenever I'd like to tag in comment the answerer, or anyone who has already written a comment below the same answer, the tag disappears.

`@name` doesn't list out the person with "name" and when I send the comment itself, it's not visible in the final result.

What's the reason, if there's any?

Comment: @name was the OP? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099

Comment: @rene it didn't work in neither case. Strangely enough, now as you can see, I can do it here, but still can't in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can't @Zolt here as well, so if you're trying that it is by-design.

Comment: @rene it's not that important anyway so yeah, I guess this is the case.