# Display comment formatting options and preview

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, markdown-preview

I browsed through many discussions on comment formatting and there doesn't seem to be one suggesting both.

I suggest showing the [available formatting options](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/text-formatting-now-allowed-in-comments-list-of-proven-and-disproven-abilities) on the side on the comment box, or at least as tooltip on a smaller question mark like the one for answer.

Users shouldn't have to come search on meta for this very useful information.

Bold, italic, and code formatting are trivial to begin with, but I didn't realize that for URL only inline works.

The URL format also calls for [reconsideration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/preview-for-comments) of comment preview. Even though I know there's no preview now, I still habitually look for it since it's such a wonderful feature when I write answers.

Comment: Yep! I agree. I had to search meta and then got to the instructions page!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

click the help link under [add comment] to see a summary of the available formatting options.

[image: commenting help]

Comment: The King is alive! Long Live the King!