# Reopen Meta Questions

Tags: discussion, meta, old-questions

I was researching whether "add a preview to the comment window" had been asked (it has, at least once, [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/preview-for-comments)) and when I found the answer I found myself wanting to bump the thread as I think it would be a useful feature (and I hate it when you forget one character on a link!). However, SE doesn't allow that (afaik).

Given that the question had been answered, I only wanted to revisit it. The current SE model is ask-answer-idle. What about re-opening, especially for meta, questions? Perhaps a new privilege?

Comment: What do you mean "closed"? The question is not closed. How about you vote the question up instead, so you make it float higher on the ['reqs' tab](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests)?

Comment: This would (also/only?) be useful for `[status-completed]` on [returning bugs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox/65792#comment-182003). (I assume the OP is referring to `[status-xx]` tags, @badp.)

Comment: What is the purpose of bumping the thread? The question has been asked and it has a valid answer too. Do you see any problems or what do you want to bump that question for?

Comment: Since comments have no formatting *beyond the* **basics**, what is the point of a preview window?

Comment: @badp's Sorry, closed was the wrong word. I will edit that out. @Will perhaps 'validate' is a better term - the preview/validate would allow you to see your comment before you hit save. @Sachin it would be to revisit the question instead of asking it again and having the duplicate closed for being a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe because [of this](http://i.imgur.com/EizMv.png), @Will? ;-) (But, agreed, errors can easily be corrected.)

Comment: (@qor, see [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020))

Comment: @Arjan, @qor72: What's the point?  You can easily add a comment, read it, and edit it if you need to change something.  Avoiding that little "I has edit" notification isn't worth a preview.

Comment: (@Arjan thanks, read!) Is it that hard to have a comment preview similar to what you get when you edit a post? Seems like the work is already done.

Comment: I agree, @Will, just wondered what edit you had to make, and if a preview would have prevented that ;-)

Comment: @qor72: Except the two are completely different.  And, if you think that changing UI to add dynamic elements while making sure everything flows well and looks good is easy, then you haven't done it before.  Practically no benefit for a fair amount of work...

Comment: @Will We've gone off topic: my question was how to restart a question that already has an answer. John has provided some insight in his answer below. Our commentary on the comment system would be best placed in the original thread. My bad for letting this drift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That question isn't closed.  I think you're referring to the phenomenon of a question, as it ages, slowing sinking away into the horde of questions where no one ever sees it anymore.

To remedy this you can:

- Add an answer
- Edit an answer
- Edit the question (perhaps with an update)
- Start a bounty

The first three will cause the question to shoot to the top of [the "Active" tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).

Adding a bounty will cause the question to be added to [the "Featured" tab.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured)

All of these basically guarantee more attention and hopefully will result in the kind of "re-opening" of the discussion that you want.

Comment: Can you add/edit/start a bounty even on a Question that already has an answer? I thought you could not, so it wouldn't kick start anything. I wanted to reopen/second that question, and request it be reevaluated as a feature.

Comment: @qor: If you have > 75 rep, you can start a bounty on any open question.  See: [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067)

Comment: I see, but how would offering a bounty on an answered question stimulate or restart the discussion of the question? The idea here is to re-kick the question after some amount of idle time.

Comment: @qor: *The idea here is to re-kick the question after some amount of idle time* Which is exactly what a bounty does.  As the bounty deadline nears, the question is elevated to the top of the featured tab where people will see it and (hopefully) act.