# Preview comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, markdown-preview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preview for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/preview-for-comments)

In 2009 there was a request for comment previewing, see [Preview for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9425/preview-for-comments). It was marked with status-declined. I'd like to see if this feature could be revisited.

Often when I use the linking mark up, I mix up the order of the () and [] or make other types of markup mistakes. When posting a question or answer, I can quickly see the mistake I've made. When I do the same for a comment, I have to submit the comment, see how it looks, and quickly try to fix it before the five minute timer runs out.

Comment: The help text is easy to get to if you forget the order of braces.

Comment: @Oded: For you it may be, but the help text isn't easy for me to find when I need to check for particular editing markup. Also, the example I've given is just one reason for having preview. Why the down vote without even a chance to discuss?

Comment: On meta, a downvote == I don't agree. And the help link is to the right of the edit box.

Comment: Five minutes should be more than enough to fix a wrongly formatted link.

Comment: @Oded: Ok, got it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Bart: Should be, but not always. If preview is technically not worth doing, I understand. It would be useful for me to see a preview, just like I can when I post a question or answer.

Comment: @Oded: re: help link. Yup, its right there. Hidden in plain sight :-[. The help link has been there all along, but now I finally see it :-)

Comment: We have an edit feature. [Never use a warning when you mean undo.](http://www.alistapart.com/comments/neveruseawarning/) Adding to the task flow would overcomplicate things.

Comment: This question is already marked as dup, it'd be better closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a mindful suggestion, but the comment system need not be convoluted further. And, like @Bart pointed out in the comments, you have the five minute period after submitting a comment to edit it, which should be more than enough time to fix broken links, spelling/grammar, and markdown errors. The 600 character limit on comments is such that comments will never be longer than an average paragraph.

Note the "help" link at the bottom right of the comment text box:

[image]

Which, when clicked, will slide open this little tool:

[image]

Comment: It might take more than five minutes to edit some ridiculous back tick / slash escaping when trying to include real and formatting ``\`` slashes or `\`` back ticks. lol! See second comment on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4512427/2087463).

Comment: Your image links are broken.