# Comment links don't handle last space in label correctly

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

Links in comments do not work correctly when the last character in the label is a space.

Example:
This works: [foo bar](http://www.foo/info)

This does not work: [foo bar](http://www.foo/info)

(in question text it apparently works)

I'll post a comment to the question to demonstrate.

As can be seen, the link is not rendered as a "label text" that is a hyperlink, but a plain text "label text" surrounded with square brackets, followed by the clickable URL in round brackets.

PS: I did several edits before getting the report correctly.

PPS: I'll try to put the "source code" here:

```
This works: [foo bar](http://www.foo/info)
This does not work: [foo bar ](http://www.foo/info)
```

Comment: This works: [foo bar](http://www.foo/info)

This does not work: [foo bar ](http://www.foo/info)