# Multiple spaces in code in comments get merged into one

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, markdown

Code is supposed to be exact and "as-is". Sometimes, showing two spaces is important. In a comment, it is not possible to show code `with  multiple   spaces`. This became apparent in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746167/regex-how-to-remove-all-non-alphanumeric-except-colon-in-a-12-24-hour-timestamp/1746195#1746195) (see comments).

EDIT: apparently this bug is larger then I thought: `multiple    spaces   here` are neither preserved in normal question text. Pity (though I couldn't find this reported before, I'd assume it is).

Workaround: use Alt+0160 (windows), or U+00A0 (Unicode NBSP), as I did in the example above.

Comment: @voyλger nice alternative workaround (but try to select and copy it).

Comment: @Abel: What is the problem? On FF, If I select the text and paste it I get the spaces on the pasted text.

Comment: I used Opera (doesn't work). Now tested with IE (doesn't work) and FF (works). Looking at the code (`<code>with </code><code> multiple </code><code> </code><code> spaces</code>`) there are spaces (but most space is created by CSS), but when selecting they aren't "blue" in any browser, and only FF copies them. Interesting little browser quirks.

Comment: @Abel: you are right, Chrome doesn't like it either. It must be because generally in HTML 1+ space becomes 1 space. I think that firefox's (pronounce it out loud, I dare you) is the *correct* behavior in this case.

Comment: Firefox is correct in *copying*, but not in *selecting*. Unfortunately, the W3 and other standards bodies say little if anything about how selections are supposed to look (or what Ctrl-C should copy consecutively), that's totally up to the UI.

Comment: Couldn't `code {white-space:pre-wrap}` be added to the SE default stylesheets?

Comment: This is still an issue, and now unicode nbsp doesn't work either (at least as far as I can test).

Comment: I guess not, @Lri, as [pre-wrap also enables newlines](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-white-space)? Those [don't get any love](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments) in comments.

Comment: @Arjan But aren't newlines removed before the CSS anyway?

Comment: No,
@Lri,
they
are
not.
(See the HTML page source for this comment.)

Comment: @Oded Can you at least post an explanation as to why it is status by design or declined instead of simply flooding the front page with your retagging?

Comment: @LoremIpsum - Sorry, trying to close old old old bugs. Didn't mean to flood the front page.

Comment: @Oded I don't mind the flooding; in fact, I'm happy the devs are closing/fixing bugs. However, without a comment/answer, I don't know if you mean "This is so old that changes since then have rendered it invalid" or "This is so lame that I don't care to respond" or "This is how it will be and I'm not going to fix it"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've added this to our stylesheets:

```
code {
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* don't collapse multiple spaces in code */
}
```

– no idea why we never did that; it's an easy enough fix, and these days it's supported by all browsers. This is in the next build.

Comment: Well, [there is *one* reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222838/since-when-are-multiline-code-comments-supported)...

Comment: @TimStone Well if that was the reason we never did it, I assume someone would've answered here :) Yep, stupid me, this behavior is right there in the spec. I read it and I still missed it.

Comment: This is [causing some problems in Firefox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227187/large-amounts-of-white-space-in-code-cause-comments-to-overflow-in-firefox).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, @animuson. Will look.

Comment: `was   this    fixed      correctly` (if so, multiple consecutive spaces should show)? Apparently not, have you reverted the change of last year?

Comment: @Abel You're right, this was removed (or rather, overwritten) during the great CSS overhaul of 2014/2015. I'll talk to the person who made that change to find out what the intention was.

Comment: So can the [tag:status-completed] be removed please?

Comment: This never made it into mobile.css, which means [this problem still exists on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299188/386992).

Answer (score 1):

You *do* have a workarround:

```
`with `` multiple `` `` spaces`
```

Looks like

```
with  multiple   spaces
```

in a comment

Comment: wowch.  I'd hate to hand parse my code to add that...

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work any longer..., see: comment with `` multiple `` `` spaces

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122520/147333) for a working workaround

Answer (score 1):

In one of my comments I've suggested to apply `sed s/  / /g`… which looks completely stupid because spaces are not rendered properly (as you can (not) see).

Now, I've tested the CSS snipset provided in a comment by Lri:

```
code { white-space:pre-wrap; }
```

It does the job of fixing this. Why isn't this applied yet?

Comment: _"Why isn't this applied yet?"_ >> my guess, it doesn't have priority. Which seems kinda odd for a site about coding though...

Comment: Or, @Abel, as [it also enables newlines](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-white-space)? Those [don't get any love](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments) in comments.

Comment: @Arjan: everything is filtered anyway for whatever illegal characters are disallowed. Can hardly think it's an issue to either replace spaces with non-breaking spaces, or to remove any \r\n.

Comment: Then I'd *not* vote for replacing spaces with non-breaking spaces, to avoid any issues with copying & pasting code fragments, @Abel. That may indeed make CSS with removing line breaks a good option then. (Though that might need some conversion of existing comments, *if* comments are sanitized upon saving rather than upon rendering.)

Comment: @Arjan: while I agree (and I think this is up to the implementers, if at all they want to do something about this), copy/pasting with nbsp's in it doesn't give me trouble with Visual Studio. Not sure of other editors though.

Comment: @Abel At least on OS X non-breaking spaces are not usually converted to normal spaces, and running code with them results in an error.