# Style inline code elements (including backticks) with white-space: pre-wrap

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, design, backtick

While writing [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4854/generate-random-boggle-board/4882#comment10264_4882), I noticed an annoying issue with the way the StackExchange software formats in-line code snippets (`<code>...</code>` or `` `...` ``) — any groups of consecutive whitespace are collapsed into a single space when the markup is displayed.  For example, if I write this:

```
To put two spaces between each element, use `array.join("  ")`.
```

It will be rendered like this:

> To put two spaces between each element, use `array.join("  ")`.

Notice that there appears to be only *one* space between the quotes in the rendered version.  Worse yet, even if you cut and paste the code snippet directly into a program, you'll most likely end up with only one space.  (At least, that's how it works in Firefox, and probably in most other browsers too.)

In posts this isn't so bad, because we can always use full code blocks if we have to, but this problem makes posting white-space sensitive code snippets in comments *very* difficult.

However, there is a **very simple fix for this problem**: just add the following CSS rule to the site style sheets:

```
code { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

This will [have the effect](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) of preventing browsers from collapsing consecutive spaces into one in code snippets.  Long lines will still wrap normally, so this change won't affect the appearance of most existing code snippets (and, where it does, I suspect the change will be an improvement at least as often as not).

As a minor side effect, this change makes browsers honor line breaks inside in-line code snippets.  I suspect at least some users (myself included) would consider this a useful feature.  If this is *not* desired for some reason, a simple work-around would be to strip line breaks from code snippets during Markdown parsing.

I've tested the effect of this change in Firefox using a local style sheet, and it seems to work fine.  The `white-space: pre-wrap` declaration is [not supported by old versions of Internet Explorer](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html) (IE7 and older), but in those browsers, the code snippets should simply continue to look as they do currently.

---

**Edit:** In the comments below, Dennis describes a workaround using non-breaking spaces (`&nbsp;`, U+00A0).  This is somewhat inconvenient in comments (or using the backtick syntax in posts), since the non-breaking spaces need to be typed in literally, but it does provide a way to display several consecutive spaces in in-line code snippets if one really needs to.  Still, the existence of this workaround doesn't eliminate the reasons for this feature request stated above.

Comment: Testing: `multiple   spaces`. Result: Multiple non-breaking spaces (`Alt-0160`) don't get collapsed.

Comment: @Dennis: Using `&nbsp;` is cheating. :-) (And, unfortunately, rather _difficult_ cheating, since you can't use HTML entities inside backticks. Alas, I believe the `Alt` key combo you suggest only works on Windows.)

Comment: True. [SuperUser: How to type special characters in Linux?](http://superuser.com/questions/59418/how-to-type-special-characters-in-linux)

Comment: Cool, thanks!  `Ctrl + Shift + U A 0` seems to work for me.  And on Firefox, it even turns those non-breaking spaces into normal spaces when I copy and paste them (although I believe this may be browser-dependent).

Comment: Has this been solved yet? Test: `array.join("  ")`. No, it seems not. I agree with the OP, multiple spaces should be enabled on inline codes.

Comment: Looks like [this has been implemented.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one) Yay!