# Prevent wrapping of inline code

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

This is silly:

[image: Screenshot of wrapped inline code]

Despite the potential for abuse along the nested-quotes lines, I think it would be a good idea to give inline code `white-space: nowrap`. [(Actually, maybe `white-space: pre`.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121930/style-inline-code-elements-including-backticks-with-white-space-pre-wrap)

It could even be restricted to the shorter, sub-20-character ones where wrapping looks the silliest.

Comment: For multiple *words* inline code, I think I still prefer the wrapping to keep line lengths balanced. (And as an aside: for comments, surprise [invisible Unicode characters are inserted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert) to prevent layout problems. I wouldn't like that to be applied to the regular posts as well.)

Comment: Yes, that’s a bad solution that stops people from copying and pasting anything. I’d rather just, you know, edit them into regular code blocks.

Comment: Yeah, the Unicode trickery is a weird choice. Even more, I *think* that using `<span style="display: inline-block"></span>` instead (like I described in [an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert/171065#171065)) solves the whole surprise while copying, but that was never used. But above all, I think that comment styling should not be different just because its width is a bit more fluent.

Comment: @minitech care to explain what you're doing with [this suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27963)? Personally I left it alone but others might not read the summary or care. (even worse, someone already voted to **approve**)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I was hoping someone would vote to approve and prove the point of the question. (What else can I do? Not enough reputation to bounty a third time.)

Comment: @minitech oh my. I didn't bother to look what post it was and what you did, assuming that by "Just leave it in the queue" you wanted nobody to actually review. You were almost there, but MSE got way less robo reviewers than SO. Now go earn some repz for another bounty! :D

Answer (score -2):

This can be totally remedied with

```
code {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

As mentioned in the question. And, I agree with your mitigation (length <= 20 chars). In fact, I think if your length is `>20` Stack Overflow should prompt to elevate the inline code into a code-block and just help the user out.