# Spacing not preserved in backtick-quoted text?

Tags: bug, code-formatting

While explaining the difference between `' '.join(x.split())` and `' '.join(x.split(None, 1))` in Python, I tried to use an example like `foo__bar` (with two spaces between `foo` and `bar`). However, with backtick-enclosed inline code, it looks wrong: `foo  bar` (two spaces) looks identical to `foo bar` (one space). It works fine in block-code context:

```
foo  bar
foo bar
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: related/dupe? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122520/how-to-write-multiple-spaces-in-the-post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one

Comment: Yeah, this is just your browser handling spaces in the `<pre>` tag differently than the `<code>` element. (Could be changed by applying `whitespace: pre` in CSS.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's possible to work around this in both inline code and comments by using a non-breaking space (which, handily, can be typed with ⇧⌥Space on a Mac keyboard): `this  is   a  test`. Still, it's a bug that would be nice to fix...

Comment: comment test: `this  is  a  test`