# Total upvotes and downvotes

Tags: bug, status-norepro, vote-count

I don't have the privilege of viewing total upvotes and downvotes on meta, but at times when I hover over the vote count the hand cursor appears and when I click, I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this

Comment: @WouterJ It doesn't happen all the time, this is the second time it happens in 3 days.

Comment: I got the same thing sometimes but you just re-vote and it works

Comment: @HugoDozois It doesn't happen when I vote, it only happens when I click on the vote count, which should not happen in the first place

Comment: @AbZy is it *just* on Meta you've noticed this?

Comment: @Rory Yeap. I have enough reputation on SO to view total counts, so the error never occured.

Comment: I just upvoted, tried, downvoted, tried, then upvoted again and tried. couldn't reproduce, but I'm sure that your correct so +1.

Comment: I had this happen to me today. It may have happened after the counter AJAX-updated (several times? who knows). Wonder if I can coordinate with someone to alter the vote count so I can test.

Comment: @nneonneo I remember it happenning to me the same way you described. Altering votes could be considered an offense I think? not really sure though.

Comment: Altering votes for the purpose of testing the voting system doesn't seem terribly abusive, as long as its done here on Meta.

Comment: Ah, but since it's your question you can't up- or downvote it. I will leave the tab open, so if someone changes the vote I can check :)

Comment: @nneonneo How about we try on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152120/208592) of yours?

Comment: Sure. I have it loaded. Up or down vote it.

Comment: Try some downvotes...

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Guess we'll just have to watch carefully for the next time it happens.

Comment: @nneonneo Yeah I guess :) But since they developers can't reproduce it, it won't be resolved. It doesn't happen that often so It shouldn't be that serious.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're even getting the option to click on the total votes, we don't hook up the click listener, title, or styles unless you've got sufficient reputation.

Perhaps a user script or browser extension is inserting those for you?

Failing that, I'll need something that correlates with the error as I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I definitely just saw this happen not too long ago. A large number of votes rolled in on [my last post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170699/bananas-in-comments), and at some point it became possible to click on the counter. It failed to fetch, just like in this example, and since then I haven't been able to click on the totals.

Comment: I don't have any extensions nor scripts installed in my google chrome. There are no steps I could provide to reproduce it. It just happens.