# How to post comment with multiple spaces in it?

Tags: support, comments, markdown, code-formatting

I know how to do that in question or answer post. But how do I write a comment post which contains multiple spaces?

I want to write this in a comment:

```
print    ("string")
```

I tried:

- Using ``` `` ```, but spaces didn't get preserved.
- Using `&nbsp;`, but it get printed exactly the way it is.
- Using `<code></code>`, same result as first one.
- Using `<pre></pre>`, same result as first one.

I am using Linux.

Comment: Related: [Multiple spaces in code in comments get merged into one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one?rq=1) (but I suspect the answer you're going to end up getting is "why would you want to do that" followed by "if it's that important, it shouldn't be a comment.")

Comment: Actually,          the answer is an actual way to leave multiple spaces in comments.

Comment: Note that using non-breaking spaces in code samples are very confusing if people would copy & paste.

Comment: @Santosh, I just want to let you know that what the poster said was inexcusable. Know that we know him well, and he's proven adept at bypassing the blocks we've put in his path. If it helps, he's pretty severely mentally ill. He's not attacking you, really, more than he's flagellating himself.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using windows, than you can hold `alt` and press `255`.  You can leave multiples of those spaces.

Apparently you have to do this on your number-pad(the row of numbers above your qwerty part doesn't work apparently).

▲
▲ ▲

Comment: @dasblinkenlight it should..... I've just checked into it a bit, and it doesn't seem to work unless you use the square number pad if you have one

Comment: @dasblinkenlight and it should work on firefox/windows, considering that's the main platform I use, and I've done it many times.  on that.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight does it not work when numlock is on?

Comment: Removing my comments as no longer relevant...

Comment: @SamIam I use Linux and doing so first takes me to 2nd tab followed by 5th tab. Is there any workaround this (any application or so?)?

Comment: If I do `Alt`+`255` on Windows (zh-HK) I get ÿ instead of any spaces.

Comment: @AlvinWong: You can edit the post from the console (using `\u00a0`), and add the text in with some jQuery.

Comment: +1. Noobs can't triforce.

Answer (score 3):

## For Linux:

Based on [@SamIam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173080/181377)'s answer  and [this post on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/59418/103134), I got the solution for my own question.

On Linux, we can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> followed by the unicode **hex** code of the character to insert that character. So taking reference from [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30020/181377) I found that hex code for a space is `00A0` or simply `A0` *(`0`s before the alphabate doesn't matter)*.

So in my case I could do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> followed by `A0`.

Google for **unicode hex table** to find some useful hex codes you can use in linux.

Comment: Now I can do `print           ("string")`.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac: press Option + Spacebar to get a non-breaking space, like   `for   example   here`  .

Note, however, that it *looks* like a space, but is not. Copy & paste will surprise people a lot, if used in a code sample. Also note that [Unicode magic is inserted in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert/171065#171065) (not just in `` `code` ``) whenever no whitespace was seen for about 80 characters, to enforce line wrapping. Such non-breaking space does not count as whitespace, so increases the chance that the Unicode magic is applied, which again is confusing for copy & paste.

And if only done to get some specific formatting, then note that things [look different on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aoeuY.png), which does not have a fixed width. One cannot really control how things look.

Comment: And like `for   example   here`.