# Multiple spaces in code markdown aren't properly rendered

Tags: bug, comments, markdown

[This bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30020/286591) was brought up and apparently fixed almost 8 years ago. However, it was brought up on [PPCG.meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12400/31716) that the problem is back.

Basically, the problem is that multiple spaces in code markdown are not shown in comments. For example, the following:

`` `...<space><space><space>...` ``

in a comment will be rendered as

`... ...`

I have tested this [in the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/289798?noredirect=1#comment960472_289798), and it seems it only shows one space regardless of how many I enter.

Comment: Fixed and reverted, as balpha says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one#comment862828_222376). He just forgot to remove the now wrong status completed tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We generally never remove status-completed tags unless they were added incorrectly. It *was* fixed and removing the tag doesn't make sense. If it's broken again, then a new bug report makes sense, as has been done here.