# Inline formatting in the Stack Exchange apps and mobile web eats spaces

Tags: bug, android-app, ios-app, mobile-web, inline-code

[My post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701051/176217) contains several lines with inline formatted code. It looks aligned in web:

> [image: Full web]

But it looks like spaces are eaten in the Android app:

> [image: Android app]

Same buggy behavior in iOS app:

> [image: iOS app]

And mobile web:

> [image: Mobile web]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-H860
- OS Version: 7.0 (1710300506712)

---

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: Unknown (iPad7,3) / iPad Pro 10.5"
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)

Comment: Possibly related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30020

Comment: The problem is `code { white-space: pre-wrap; }` (the reason that it works right on desktop view) is only in [primary.css](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/primary.css?v=1a040064279b), not [mobile.css](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/mobile.css?v=a53e285a659a).