# Is there a way to go to next line in a comment on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments, linebreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about newlines within comments ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments)

Is there a way to go to next line in a comment on Stack Overflow?

Comment: No, I don't think so.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean is there a way to insert a newline? No, comments only support a subset of the formatting options available to answers; they're detailed in [this faq entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-does-the-comment-system-and-comments-work) and [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)