# How insert a carriage return in a comment? Is it possible?

Tags: support, comments, linebreak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How about newlines within comments ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments)

How can I do it? I tried the "two spaces thing" and it didn't work. Is it really not possible to enter a carriage return in a comment?

Thanks and sorry for such a lame question.

Comment: Comments only support a limited form of markdown and no HTML support. As such, there is no support for new lines of any form. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/stack-overflow-comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks for more details. Also, you shouldn't apologize for asking an honest question, even if it seems so simple.

Comment: This is technically a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53576/is-there-a-way-to-go-to-next-line-in-a-comment-on-stack-overflow-closed, but since that one is closed I will be instead voting for the root at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments that addresses newlines specifically.

Comment: You can't. _____________________________________________________________________________________________________
But you can be obnoxious and cheat.

Comment: @perbert: Your overlong underscores    broke the layout in Firefox :(

Comment: They don't?♪Checking...◙Checking
Nope...

Answer (score 1):

As Grace Note noted :) Comment don't support newlines: [Comments don't have formatting tags or line breaks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50444/stack-overflow-comments-dont-have-formatting-tags-or-line-breaks)