# Comment UI is not friendly enough

Tags: discussion, comments

I am new to Stack Overflow, and have quickly found that the comment box (that is, commenting on someone's answer/suggestion) is really, really, really bad.

Reasons why:

1. Hitting Enter while typing results in the "accept comment" button being hit. What? Am I supposed to type HTML code for CRLF? Is this slashdot? This is terrible design.
2. No formatting buttons. A new question or answer has all kinds of formatting exposed. But the comments get none. This is bad. It makes it more difficult to comment on a suggestion with blocks of code or other formatting.
3. It automatically turns typed text into "friendly" text. Example: If I type a URL into the comment box, it turns it into a link and removes "http://" from it. That isn't what I wanted. I typed what I wanted, and then the site went and mutilated it.

Overall, I have to rate the comment box 0 out of 10. It's not only incredibly lacking in features, but it actually mutilates what I typed into something I didn't type, without even asking me. Bad. Just plain bad.

Comment: Guess what, we don't care all that much about comments. Questions and answers are what drive these sites. Comments are second class citizens at best.

Comment: CRLF? In comments?? Why???

Comment: Comments are not meant to be extensive answers nor extensive questions. You should not put code block in comments, maybe a line, but surely not a block. For more help about comment formatting see [Comment Formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: This isn't a forum. Comments are just for nudging the poster to improve his/her post. They are ephermal, and may be deleted anythime. We don't care much about them.

Comment: I agree on the first 2 points, but I like the way it handles hyperlinks.

Comment: Reading the title, I thought you were saying that in general, comments stink (not that the comment workflow stinks).  I was about to vote that up, and then I read your post.

Comment: Regarding the CRLF thing specifically: [Pressing Enter in comment box unexpectedly submits form](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form) (see Jeff's comment, #3 overall)

Comment: Don't even get me started on titles and tags!

Comment: @BilltheLizard Multi-line tags would be AWESOME!

Comment: @itwally I'm just curious: why did you not simply address this constructively? Why run in as a new user and tell everybody that everything sucks? Why not simply ask why it is the way it is, and what the community thinks about your possible improvements? It might still not have been agreed with, but you would have made yourself less of a downvote target. You're by no means the only one to do this, but I always wonder what makes users do this...

Comment: What type of formatting do you need that is not available? Have you read the help that is available for formatting comments? What does it not provide that is absolutely necessary? You are able to use _italic_, **bold**, or write `code` in comments. If you want to add an url that is not a link, just use a code block such as `http://google.com/`. The only other thing you have requested is new lines; however, comments are meant to be short so they should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 30):

You're right. Comments are terrible. This is particularly obvious when you contrast the comment UX with the one available for answers.

It's almost as though the system is subtly suggesting that answers are preferable to comments.

Comment: I wonder what other subliminal messages you've worked into the system...

Comment: btw I don't mind the subliminal messages, but I hope at least you are being compliant to the standard: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1097

Comment: Little-known fact: if you play MSO backwards, it's a Beatles song.

Comment: But the thing is this:  sometimes an answer is WRONG.  Or needs FIXED.  And the comments section is the logical place for feedback when that happens.  The near-complete lack of formatting hinders communication -- it makes it more difficult to do that.  That's just plain bad.

Comment: Then write a better one, @Itwally - or edit the existing one.

Comment: @itwally Again what lack of formatting? You can do _italics_, **bold**, and put `code` in comments. What else do you need? You are saying it is bad, but the only thing you claim it is missing is new lines. Comments are supposed to be short. Why do we need to have paragraphs in comments? If it is missing something else, make your point clear because even after all this commenting you have made no new arguments.

Comment: That's often the reply of *nix folks.  And it's every bit as wrong here as it is there.  Valid criticism helps make a product better.  Sitting silently while bad design is created and enforced does not.

Comment: @ltwally There's a distinct lack of suggestion for a list/description formatting functionality that's missing in your comment.  He specifically asked you to provide the valid criticism you feel is so helpful and you choose not to provide any examples; instead you criticized him for now allowing you to provide your criticism (despite the fact that it's *exactly* what he was doing).

Comment: @Itwally so *edit the existing answer to make it better.*

Comment: Regarding my prior comment, it was in reply to Shog9.  At the time, the comment from Josh Mein was not displayed on my browser.  Apologies for not putting the @shog9 there.

Comment: Look, @ltwally - if you wanna leave criticisms, leave comments. Simple, clear, constructive *textual* comments. If you want to *fix* a *wrong* answer, then there are better ways to do that than trying to cram all of your fixes into a comment. Also, please don't waste my time here by claiming you want to fix something and then getting upset when I suggest that you go right ahead and do that.

Comment: @Itwally the "write a better one" was in reference to *answers*, not the entirety of Stack Overflow. If an answer sucks so bad you need to write entire code blocks to corrected it, you should probably just post a full answer that's correct.

Answer (score 10):

1. No, you're supposed to hit shift+enter (although the new-line will be suppressed anyway, by design).  To educate the user of this, we do exactly what we do.  This is pretty standard design.  Just to name one obscure company that does it this way, take a gander at [Facebook](http://facebook.com).
2. It fits the majority use case and keeps comments shorter and less distracting from Q/A.

Anyway, you're also wrong - comments are pretty well-featured:  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting.  Yes, you would have to dig around to find this, but that's also true of answers, unless you're one of the rare people who masters markdown before visiting your first SE site.

More fully-featured comments would detract from answers and promote extended discussion, which is the opposite of what this site is for.

Comment: "No, you're supposed to hit shift+enter" newlines are suppressed in comments anyway (for good reason)

Answer (score -10):

It would be great if newlines would work in some fashion in the comments, and if there were formatting tools for them.

I see no use case for NOT shortening the URLs, if you need it all in there as text then enclose it with backticks.

Related Feature Requests (pointed out by Popular Demand):

[Fix the Bad Behavior of submitting the Comments upon hitting Enter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63644/13295).

[How About Newlines Within Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/13295)

[Greasemonkey Workaround for Newline entering Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71837/13295)

Comment: You may also be interested in the much older [How about newlines within comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/how-about-newlines-within-comments)

Comment: What would be so great about newlines in comments?

Comment: If my comment isn't meant as a link, but is instead a reply to a suggestion, which includes a URL...  it's very frustrating that this site automatically thinks it should remove the http:// from it.  So, yes, there are very good usage examples of not wanting this done.  Not even being presented with the option is not user-friendly, not intuitive, not good.

Comment: @Yannis, see Jon Skeet's answer.

Comment: [This is the use case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818159/use-http-auth-to-redirect#comment22501922_1581867). Of course hek2mgl explained that the OP needed to use backticks in that case

Comment: @ltwally, you can enclose it in backticks if you don't want it to be a link.

Comment: YANNIS:  by CRLF, I mean a new line.  Having the Enter key not generate a new line, but instead have it target the "Add Comment" button, is not intuitive, is not good UI, is just plain not good.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Jon Skeet's answer is void since you can't really ping more than one person anymore.

Comment: @Lance Oh come on, you know that answer doesn't make sense anymore, you can't reply to more than one person per comment.

Comment: @ltwally: It is * perfectly* good UI. When a textbox automatically submits on ENTER, the next intuition I (and approx 98% of this site users, apparently) is to try SHIFT+ENTER, that's perfectly fine.

Comment: Lance:  That's great.  But it's not intuitive.  Who here, when they first joined the site thought to do that right off?  The answer:  No one.  And that makes it bad design.  Good design would be putting brackets on it if I wanted it to have the http:// removed.

Comment: @ltwally I know what you mean. What I don't know is why you need newlines in comments in the first place.

Comment: So, to not have this site mangle a URL that I typed, I have to enclose it in brackets [].

And, to generate a new-line, I have to use Shift-Enter instead of just Enter.

What UI is this supposed to emulate?  Who here found this intuitive?  NO ONE.  And that, my new friends, makes it a really terrible UI.  Good UI works like people expect it to.  This site's comments do not.

Comment: @ltwally There are no newlines in comments (even with shift-enter).

Comment: Yannis:  My previous comment had three (very small) paragraphs.  Humans naturally separate things into paragraphs.  Even after using Shift-Enter, this site removed that formatting.  It changed what I typed into something more difficult to read.  Whoever is in charge of this..  BAD, BAD, BAD CODE MONKEY.

Comment: @ltwally, not brackets, backticks, ```.

Comment: Formatting makes things easier to read, and easier to communicate.  Lack of formatting -- making everything one jumbled paragraph, makes things harder to read and thus hinders good communication.  I know this is a site for coders... but, seriously, didn't anyone pay attention in their university Technical Writing course?

Comment: @ltwally: Comments aren't _for_ paragraphs. On meta paragraphs may be useful, but not on main.

Comment: @manishearth:  So, what?  What is the proper way to respond to a suggestion?  Another suggestion?  That doesn't seem logical at all.

Comment: @ltwally You appear to still be missing the point: Comments should be short. If we allow paragraphs people will want bulleted lists, then headings, then more characters, etc. - At some point they're equal to answers, and Stack Exchange is a forum like any other, filled with noise and crap.

Comment: @ltwally: What? Sure, you may want to respond to  suggestion. But the comment is really only meant to be read by a few, and probably will be deleted later. In light of this, making comments look as low-key as possible (and making sure that they don't take up much space) is the best idea.

Comment: @ltwally Just because *you* didn't expect the behavior seen doesn't mean nobody did.  I find the UI completely intuitive and it behaves exactly as I expected it to from the moment I started using the site.  You != Everybody.

Comment: votetaq7: So where is the proper place to reply to a suggestion?  The comments seem to me where this should happen.  Is everything supposed to be a suggestion?  Do I have to use "answer your question" for every single reply if I don't want to have formatting so basic it makes me crave an old-fashioned type-writer?  That is just plain absurd.  Every bulletin board on the planet works better than that.

Comment: And guess what, this is not a bulletin board. It's a Q&A...not even a Q&A&C

Comment: @ltwally If that's how you feel, then feel free to use every bulletin board on the planet but Stack Overflow (which isn't really a bulletin board to begin with).

Comment: @ltwally Well, most bulletin boards on the planet are full of crap, unlike SO which has much less of it.  It's UI design is a large factor in that.  So while it's clearly very different for you, that difference is what has generated the highly preferable result.  In short, if you would like to use the site (which you're more than welcome to do) get used to it, don't expect it to become just another forum, because we don't want that.

Comment: Yannis, Servy, My point remains, and it remains valid: Discussing, refining, and _commenting_ on a suggestion is done in the comments section, yes?  And the comments section lacks horrible bad in formatting, which impedes communication.  I did not say that I wished SO was another crappy BB.  Only that those crappy BB's have superior formatting, and thus superior communication, to SO.  I haven't seen a one of you actually refute that; you only say "get used to it".  Bad is bad.  This site's comments are bad.

Comment: @Servy perhaps you found Unix's VI to be intuitive, too.  For every group, there's always the 1%.  None-the-less, serving the 1% that find a UI intuitive against the 99% that do not is not generally considered good UI design.

Comment: @ltwally Well, considering that all of the people here seem to be managing just fine, and I haven't heard people complaining about it besides you until now, it would seem that *you* are in that small minority, not me.  That said, it's not particularly new or innovative.  It's the exact same UI experience as any [decent] chat program I've ever used.

Comment: @servy, see the feature-requests I linked to to see that others care about it also.

Comment: Servy, I might be in the minority willing to comment about it, where as the majority just adjust or go elsewhere.  But telling me that the majority of people think this is good?  That's absurd.

Comment: @LanceRoberts They are complaining about an entirely different issue than all of the issues the OP here is.  It's also a very old question.  As I said, *I* hadn't seen others complaining about this issue.

Comment: @ltwally What makes you more qualified to speak to what the majority of SO users think is good than me?

Comment: @LanceRoberts Also, looking at that thread, by the sound of it they just added that behavior right when that question was asked, so the issue is that all of the SO users had gotten used to enter not submitting comments, and then all of a sudden it did.  Now that people are used to the opposite, you'd see the exact opposite reaction were the feature to be taken away (I know for one I'd be pissed).

Comment: @Servy, I agree that you're right that people have adjusted and are used to the bad UI, and would probably fight to change it.  It's amazing what people can get used to (me included).

Comment: @LanceRoberts I reject your assertion that it's a bad UI.  You don't like it; that's okay.  That doesn't make it bad.  Also note that user expectations of UIs change over time.  This behavior wasn't nearly as widespread 10 years ago, but now it's seen in a lot more places, so it takes much less time for someone to get used to the concept of enter being submit rather than newline.

Comment: Lance:  One thing I've noticed over the years is the pequliar personality traits of ... well, geeks.  Most IT folks fall into that category, myself included.  And it's not unusual to see them embrace UI designs that everyone else automatically rejects.  It's like a badge of honor.  And then they will fight to the death to defend that UI.  Visit any hard-core linux chat room for an example.  Watch them pounce on newbies that find VI's commands hard to use.  Thing is, those linux zealots are wrong even if they don't know it.  Same applies here.

Comment: @Servy "What makes you more qualified to speak to what the majority of SO users think is good than me?"  Good UI design is intuitive for new users, whatever the product.  This site's comment section does not work like most any other similar product.  That makes it bad.  It has nothing to do with you or me, or what your personal preferences are.  I, myself, am not an Apple fan.  But I am capable of recognising that most people intuitively grasp how to operate their UI's.  That makes them good UI's.  This site is non-intuitive.  That makes it bad.

Comment: @ltwally Even if we accept your premise (which I don't) that this particular UI trait is only well received by geeks, I would say, "what's the problem, that's the target audience".

Comment: @ltwally `"This site's comment section does not work like most any other similar product."`  Incorrect.  There are *many* products using this exact UI trait.  As I said before, any [good] chat application that I've ever used has this exact trait.  Newlines are either not used, or require shift-enter, and enter submits the text.  The underlying issue here (as has been made clear throughout this thread) is that you feel a comment is a full fledged post.  The site disagrees.  It is not a full fledged post, it's basically a small chat screen that happens to persist itself.

Comment: @Servy:  How many geeks expect the Enter key to, instead of generating a new-line, instead activate the Add Comment button?  I'll go out on a limb and say, "very few."  Because almost nothing else works like that.  That makes it unintuitive.  And that makes it bad UI design.  The fact that it has no new lines at all means it hampers communication.  It's been 10 yars since I took a technical writing course, but I do remember one of the primary lessons they tried to push into us geeks was to make what we wrote easy to understand.  New lines allows this to happen.  Removing new lines hinders.

Comment: I think the big problem is that Facebook started doing it, so everyone else felt they had to copy (though Facebook allows newlines using Shift).

Comment: @Servy, I've used many chat clients, and I refute your example.  Most of them use Enter for new line, and Shift-Enter for send.  And the reason is simple:  Every other application on Earth uses Enter for a new line.

Comment: @ltwally That's because you're trying to write an essay into a comment.  **That's not what comments are for**.  You're doing it wrong by thinking that comments are the correct place for that type of information.  The fact that the UI is not intuative for you is a direct result of the fact that the entire purpose of the feature was misunderstood by you.  That is understandable, it is very different *on a functional level, not a UI level* from most of it's competitors.  Once you get over that, the UI differences are pretty trivial.

Comment: @LanceRoberts emulating facebook... now that's shameful.

Comment: @ltwally I've never used a chat client, ever, that has that behavior.  I can think of a dozen or so off of the top of my head that have the behavior I've described.

Comment: @LanceRoberts This particular UI trait has been around long before facebook.  That's one popular recent example of it, that's all.  Unless a dev would come and say otherwise, I'd doubt the assertion that the motivation came from there.

Comment: @servy the purpose does not change bad UI into good UI.  And, on a functional level, no matter how much talent comes to this site for Q&A, not having an effective way to establish dialog about a proposed answer is ... exasperating.  I can only surmise that the creators didn't really care if the answer needed feedback for improvement or bug-fixes.  Because that's not really possible with this limited comment system.  And I find that a rather poor design choice.  BAD CODE MONKEY. BAD BAD!

Comment: @servy " I can think of a dozen or so off of the top of my head that have the behavior I've described."  I'll call your bluff.  Go.

Comment: `"the purpose does not change bad UI into good UI"` As you have said, the quality of a UI is based in large part (although not entirely on) whether the expectations of the user are met.  If your expectation of what the entire purpose of a particular UI component is incorrect, and if the UI is based on the expectations of someone who correctly understands what the component is for, then the two expectations won't match.  If you think that the Google search textbox is a good place to write a letter to Google it will seem like terrible UI (why no can haz linebreaks?!?).

Comment: @ltwally Challenge accepted! AIM, MSN messanger, mIRC, every single Java applet I've ever used for IRC chat (I don't know their names, but I've used at least 3-4), SE's chat, Skype, the ingame chat of most fullscreen games that I've played (although here sometimes shift-enter is used to differentiate show to everyone vs show to team/group/whatever) I assue you don't want me to start listing them all..., Facebook (just to piss you off ;), and MS Lync.

Comment: @ltwally, See the link I added in my answer for a greasemonkey workaround to not have newline submit comments.