# markdown editing in comments, 5 minutes only and paragraphs

Tags: support, comments, markdown, markdown-preview

If I answer as an 'answer' I get the good-looking UI to help me do all the things I want, BUT if I am in comments I am helpless. Would it take much resources to have the same same UI to keep sanity in answers too ?

The other query is, is there a way to test the output/look as we do when framing a question? For people who are not so good at markdown will appreciate if this can be done.

Lastly I tried retext and saw the preview there of the comment till I was happy with. Copying and pasting it there makes it a jumble.

```
$ aptitude show retext
Package: retext                          
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Version: 5.0.0-1
Priority: optional
Section: editors
Maintainer: Dmitry Shachnev <mitya57@gmail.com>
Architecture: all
Uncompressed Size: 417 k
Depends: python3-markups, python3-pyqt5, python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit, python3:any (>= 3.3.2-2~)
Recommends: docutils-common (>= 0.10-3~), python3-enchant, python3-markdown | python3-docutils, shared-mime-info (>= 0.91)
Breaks: retext-wpgen (< 4.0~)
Replaces: retext-wpgen (< 4.0~)
Description: Simple text editor for Markdown and reStructuredText
 ReText is a simple editor for Markdown and reStructuredText markup languages. 

 ReText supports tabs, live text preview and syntax highlighting. Supported export formats: HTML, ODT, PDF. It is also possible to write custom
 export extensions. 

 It is written in Python using Qt libraries.
Homepage: http://retext.sourceforge.net/
```

Hoping people can help.

The comment in question for now is [Does anybody know if any daemons or services started by default when TBB is installed in Debian?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4197/does-anybody-know-if-any-daemons-or-services-started-by-default-when-tbb-is-inst/4201#comment4119_4201) but there have been other comments where I had same issues.

Comment: Comments support a small subset of markdown (click the `help` link next to the comment edit box for details). We do **not** want to support the full markdown array for a feature we see as secondary to the purpose of the site.

Comment: Related: [How about newlines within comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197/262755)

Comment: @FishBelowtheIce thank you, wanted to know the same and did try to search but failed. Thank you for sharing the originals and the related questions. It seems I have to live within these boundaries :(

Answer (score 2):

Comments are second-class citizens (its quoted from someone, can't remember who he was).

Comments are not designed to put large amounts of code - why do you need to put it in comment? If it is clarification to your question, edit the question instead. If it is an answer, write it as an answer.

5 mins of editing period is because comments don't support revision history - you can't know when it was changed and what was changed.