# What's the best of Stack?

Tags: discussion, community-vp-questions

Continuing with my series of questions to you - I've got one that's a bit lighter this week. We spent last week firing up our magic wand and changing things.  This time, let's celebrate what exists.

I want to know about your favorite contributions (questions, answers, or comments!).  These can be serious or funny, poignant or cavalier…

- Do you have a favorite contribution that **you** have written on one of the sites?
- Do you have a favorite contribution that **someone else** added?  What is it?  Why do you like it?

So many of you have weighed in each week on my questions, and I'm learning a ton.  Thank you!

Comment: ...can this be something on Stack that's not precisely a question, answer, or comment...?

Comment: @Mithical Is it your unrivaled reign over the starboard in the Tavern?

Comment: @Mithical, i'm allowing for broad discretion here. But reserving the right to heckle if I think you go too far.

Comment: It's too late, I've posted it already! Mwahahaha...

Comment: @Philippe, as much as I like your title, we kinda have a policy to **not** put tags up there...

Comment: @Luuklag To be fair, he started the tradition of using it in the title before the tag existed.

Comment: So we need a new tag then @Catija ;)

Comment: @Luuklag- I have zero ego wrapped up in it; if we need to change it, change it.  I would like to ask, though... why?  You say there's a policy around it, and that's fine, but when someone gives that as a reason, I typically push a little and find out why that policy exists.  If there's a good reason, great.  If not, maybe it should be revisited so we're not complying with policy for policy sake, and so we can start citing the actual reason, rather than the policy. :-)

Comment: Redundancy, mostly, but also to prevent people tag spamming their titles. IMO the policy can be ignored in this scenario

Comment: [This is the policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/345161), I think, but in this case an exception to the rule sounds preferable.

Comment: @Luuklag In my opinion the tag is the problem, not the title. I’m not sure it’s a good idea to have an entire tag reserved for a subset of one person’s questions. A more useful tag could be applied to any of these sorts of open-ended questions asked by the company to get feedback from the community instead of just Phillippe’s.

Comment: Fair point Philippe, and also I'm not looking to "enforce" any of that rule, otherwise I'd done so already ;) As to the why, the link @TheLethalCarrot posted explains. Mostly because it is redundant, and for that reason does not fit within the philosophy of SE; Just Questions and Answers, no distractions. ps. I love you asking for the why, rather then blatently complying or declaring the policy stupid :)

Comment: @ColleenV, that seems reasonable to me.

Comment: @Luuklag - I was the kid you hate. WHY?  WHYYYY?  BUT WHYYYYYY?

Comment: @Philippe I can relate ;)

Comment: "Stack" is jargon from inside the company. Can you keep to the official names, please?

Comment: It does kinda sidestep the Stack Exchange doing business as Stack Overflow problem 

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge about it.. by My yodeda has a day  a year when all the question answers are mean to be just funny... maybe some mod over there can punch in?

Comment: Philippe: I like that you are using Meta to ask the community help on getting insights about SE, but is it really necessary to include "Community VP" in the title of "all" your posts (strictly not all your questions have that... but it's becoming "a tradition") ? Since nowadays we have user tags for diamond moderators and staff, I'm wondering if instead of you being tagged as Staff use `CVP` or another short form of "Community VP" with a purple background and sparkles :D.

Comment: FYI, I don't think I ever see community members call it "Stack". That seems to be a term that's exclusively used by staff.

Comment: @curiousdannii I've seen quite a few users do that. I personally don't like it either, since it doesn't really make sense, but it's by far not something only SE people say.

Comment: @curiousdannii, i refer you to the very first comment above.  :-)

Comment: Probably just use "Stack" for your benefit ;)

Comment: @curiousdannii.  Could be.  Very friendly of them. :P

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to my profile, but I'm philippe@stackoverflow.com. :-)

Answer (score 26):

I don't have any contributions I'm really that proud of (enough to list here at least), but my favorite contribution from someone else (here, it's several people) has got to be:

#### [Build a working game of Tetris in Conway's Game of Life](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/11880/build-a-working-game-of-tetris-in-conways-game-of-life) (specifically the answers)

For reference, Game of Life is a simulation on a grid of living and dead cells. Each cell has eight neighbors, since corners count. If a living cell has 2 or 3 cells next to it, it stays alive; otherwise, it dies from loneliness or overcrowding. If a dead cell has exactly 3 living cells next to it, it comes back to life. This is actually able to compute anything computable, but is extremely difficult to manipulate. Yet, people managed to implement a real game of Tetris using such a simple system.

The question was posted in mid 2013. The answers were posted in fall of 2017. A team of people worked on this project throughout pretty much that entire period of time. The reason I like this so much is that in many ways, I think it reflects the nature of our site (Code Golf) - we're that one* weird site that doesn't do Q&A and instead has fun and does challenges for fun, yet even though it's oriented around competition, we have a really strong community, people love collaborating and helping each other on their competitive submissions all the time, and we're willing to put forth high effort for totally impractical things.

<sup>*actually we're not the only weird site; we're not even the only non-Q&A site, but I think we cause the most headaches in terms of our structure and needs (not in terms of causing trouble or whatever)</sup>

Comment: Omg that post is completely insane! Thank you for sharing this!!!

Answer (score 21):

My all time favorite Stack Exchange answer was posted by [tchrist](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2085/tchrist) on ELU. [The question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/196354/25030) is asking for a name to describe a body of water that is large enough to have a reasonable chance of containing fish and, therefore, be suitable for fishing in. [The answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/196393/25030) is a delight to read:

> A *piscary* is a body of water natural or artificial (a *piscine* would only be an artificial one) under active *piscicultural* care to render it fit for *piscation* and related *piscatorial*—or simply *piscatory*—pursuits perpetrated by *piscivorous piscators*, at which point said *piscose* body will be perfectly ***pisculent*** — that is, it will be fit for fishing.
>
> But I predict a potential problem if you go with *pisculent* and
> related terms.
>
> Although all these words are of obvious meaning and attested by the
> OED, it is always possible that some petty pissants hearing such words
> will perceive them as presenting the pissants not with a *piscary* but
> with a *pissoir*, and perforce pitch a personal pot of puissant poison
> into your pretty poisson pond in a puerile act of *piscicide* instead
> of fishing it per your preference.
>
> Pity, that.

There are 36 different words beginning with `p` there.

Comment: Perhaps this is potentially pretty pretentious, but personally I'm partial to pure, pristine praiseworthy prose (predictably)! Pray, is there possibly a particular reason this (s)pecific preeminent Perl programmer produced the post? (Translation: Was there any particular inspiration for the answer's choice of wording?)

Comment: @HDE226868 we'd have to ask him, but he is very much a language geek and is a professional writer as well as a Perl programmer, so the quality of the prose is not surprising. Tom's one of the main reasons the Perl documentation is so well written.

Comment: Sounds like they may have just watched *V for Vendetta* before writing that answer :p

Comment: @JonClements, Jon, Jon. V for Vendetta should be _read_ not watched! ;)

Comment: @terdon well... I've always had a soft spot for Natalie Portman so... :)

Comment: I'm just horsing around, @JonClements. I liked the movie, I just _really_ liked the comic which I had read many years before the movie came out so _V for Vendetta_ will always be a thing to read rather than watch in my mind.

Comment: @terdon - Preposterous!

Answer (score 20):

Ooh, that's a tough choice. There are so many gems (less or well-known) in the network which deserve a place in the Internet Hall of Fame. I'll nominate the [famous answer to why you shouldn't try to parse HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4751173). It's a unique work of art and truly shows what kind of things are possible within the limits of Markdown and Unicode. Alas, it's too short to win the Nobel Prize for literature...

As for my own contributions, I particularly like [this funny comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187829/why-did-peter-jackson-replace-glorfindels-role-with-arwen#comment510998_187829) where I'm trying to let one of the characters in the question [break the fourth wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_wall).

Comment: Hah- that answer checks out, for sure. :P

Answer (score 18):

My favorite thing on Stack, while not precisely a question, answer, *or* comment, is probably the D&D group we've formulated over on Puzzling.SE.

None of the members of the group knew each other beforehand; we all met in Puzzling chat. We come from wildly different backgrounds; for a group made up of around six people, we've got quite the mix of countries, cultures, timezones, identities... who all came together to play a role-playing game and talk about dragons.

With the fact that the members were spread across the world I'd be starting a session at midnight and finishing at two–three in the morning. I learned the rules of Dungeons & Dragons, patiently explained by the other players. We named dragons after breakfast foods. Had dozens of sessions, spread across months.

We did have to take a break for now because some schedules changed and it's harder to find a time that works, but hopefully that won't be for long. (We've also got a Discord server for conversations that SE may not be the best place for.)

All in all, it's a perfect example of the way in which a platform like SE can be used to build community bonds and friendships in way that the people who designed the platform probably never imagined. (And yes, you can read [transcripts of our sessions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/118089/pse-dd-chatroom?tab=conversations).)

Comment: If I upvote this, is that a conflict of interest? :) I love our queer group as well!

Comment: I'll allow it :)

Comment: <3 to you too, Mith!

Answer (score 16):

### What is "my guy syndrome" and how do I handle it?

My Guy Syndrome is a trap that has befallen many table top RPG players. Alex P explains in [their answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/37105/62294):

> "My Guy" syndrome is when — often unwittingly — you disclaim decision-making power and responsibility by acting like "what my character would do" is inevitable and inviolable, even if it gets in the way of actually having fun in the game or being able to play the game at all.

Alex P goes on to help us diagnose and treat the symptoms of My Guy Syndrome. For good reason, this is the highest scoring answer on RPG.SE - the experience is near universal, and Alex's answer equips us to deal with it head on.

Comment: I like that post a lot because it is accessible to both avid RPGers and folks with just a passing interest.

Comment: I've referenced this post outside the context of tabletop RPGs as well - it's quite flexible and broadly applicable.

Answer (score 13):

This is a really tough question because, like everyone else, I've seen so many great posts over the years. One of my favorite answers is [an analysis of the orbit of a satellite orbiting a ringworld](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/79952/627), performed by [typesanitizer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/37356/typesanitizer?tab=profile). They wrote a really nice description of how a ring-shaped world's gravitational field would differ from that of Earth's, then wrote some Mathematica code to show how a satellite would follow an interesting helical trajectory:

[image: Helical trajectory around a ringworld.]

The answer stuck out to me for a few reasons:

- I like it because the question is one that anyone can understand, and while solving the problem certainly isn't trivial, everyone can appreciate the answer regardless of their physics background.
- The non-code bits aren't too long or jargon-y, a pit that's easy to fall into.
- This was the user's first post on the site! It definitely takes a lot of courage to step up and immediately write such a comprehensive answer, and I tip my cap to typesanitizer for having the courage to make that jump.

---

I tend to be fairly critical of my writing, but my favorite post *I've* written might be [this answer about future radio telescopes](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/39951/2153) in the aftermath of [the loss of the 300-meter dish at the Arecibo Observatory](https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-03552-2) in late 2020. I had just started my PhD, and suddenly one of the two most important instruments to my work was lost. It was a difficult time for a lot of folks in the radio astronomy community, and I found it cathartic to think and write about the positive things that lie ahead for our field, even in the wake of tragedy. It was also great to see that the general public . . . well, *cared*. That honestly meant a heck of a lot to me.

Comment: Word.  That's freaking awesome.  I went and read the answer by typesanitizer, and it blew my mind.  Sent it to my dad, who's a physics geek.

Answer (score 11):

There's no one particular favorite contribution I've made. Regarding someone else's contribution, though, there's [Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/811/shog9)'s Meta question [Stack Overflow 2020 Q1&2 Company Commitments Report Card](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351024/562482). Even though he was [let go](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/562482) by the company only about 6 months before, we were fortunate that he still put in a lot of time & effort (along with getting help from several "current and former SO/SE users", along with "Jack Daniel's Tennessee Whiskey, for inspiration and motivation") to write an interesting & quite detailed summary in the form of a report card about a lot of information, namely of the various company commitments (and the progress on them) over a period of half of a year. I think he did an excellent job summarizing everything but, regarding his grades, I agree with several other people that he was at times being somewhat generous.

This post also came at an important time considering the overall relationship between the company and community was just starting to improve after a disastrous second half of 2019. It helped to remind at least me, and I trust others as well, that the company had made various important commitments and were following through on them to various degrees. The post provided a good summary of these commitments, as well as to what extent they have been implemented so far, which could be used to refer back to when checking later on how much more progress had been made on them.

Comment: I wonder how many of those he'll do... I, for one, would like to see another.

Comment: @Ollie I would also love to see another one from him at some point.

Comment: That was a great read, thanks for sharing.

Comment: I was considering an answer with a link to just all Shog9 posts but I guess this better illustrates the value overall of his contributions.

Answer (score 10):

### When we found the [Story where the number 3 is the monster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2937/3804)

Sci-Fi Stack exchange has a bit of a reputation for identifying stories, and really this whole post is about that. But the linked question is really an exemplar of that.

It sat unanswered for 4 years before somebody managed to post an accurate answer, get the accept and over 5k rep in bounties.

Until then it had been sort of the stack's white whale, never been able to be found:

> Fantastic, Kyle! In case you didn't know, this is the single most famous unanswered question on the site: it's been referred to for *years* as ["the big white whale of unanswered questions"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/16419846#16419846) and said to be [unanswerable](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=23697222#23697222). Answering this will [guarantee you instant celebrity](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23696141#23696141) and probably tons of bounties. A resounding welcome to SFF.SE!

~ [Rand al'Thor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor)

Comment: I love this!  And it was his first post!

Answer (score 10):

I guess I'm a bit late here, but...

**[CRIME - How to beat the BEAST successor?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19914/235964)**

---

When security researchers Juliano Rizzo and Thai Duong announced that they had found a major flaw in TLS - the protocol that secures communications on the internet - a flaw that allowed them to decrypt authentication cookies to hijack sessions, the infosec community was, understandably, both concerned and curious. What exactly was this subtle vulnerability that had been missed by all the security researchers and cryptographers for so long?

Someone decided to go ask on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com). Naturally, the first response they received was along the lines of "Dude, until those guys publish what they've found, what can we say?" And that would have been enough for most people. Not so for The Bear. Instead of sitting down and waiting patiently for the researchers to tell everybody what the vulnerability was, he went and (re)discovered the vulnerability *all by himself*, ten days before it was scheduled to be released to the public. And then he wrote a wonderful answer explaining how it all worked, so that even a relative newbie could understand. If that doesn't demonstrate the amount of talent and expertise that is present on the Stack Exchange Network, I don't know what does.

Comment: This. Is. Amazing.    This may be one of the best examples that I’ve seen of the sheer intellect on this network.

Comment: That *is* amazing. [Steve Gibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Gibson_(computer_programmer)) may have [a rival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Now).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I'm not sure if you meant that as a compliment or a snark. You see, most of the infosec community doesn't hold Mr. Gibson in high esteem.

Comment: nobody - I very nearly posted that one as well - the fun as @pornin developed his answer, as well as the briefing I could give my organisation so we were prepared in advance of formal publication meant this was just an awesome piece of work.

Answer (score 9):

There was once a big storm. Dark clouds covered the skies. The sun was nowhere to be seen, and things were dark and gloomy.

People were shouting and crying for help, but their shouts caused the reverse effect of what they wanted to achieve.

And then it came.

Guiding hand, the voice of reason. Bridge between the two worlds.

Someone who understood the shouts for what they actually were, and was able to explain this to those above.

Think that's enough, and clearly I'm talking about [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331546/152859) here on Meta Stack Exchange. This marked the beginning of the great change Stack Exchange went through. Maybe there were other forces at work, which I didn't see, but surely this was a great step towards changing the attitude inside SE management from "Let's get rid of Meta" to "Let's work with the people of Meta".

Also, in case I didn't say it enough I'll say it again...

**Thank you, Yaakov!**

Comment: i mean... did a change actually occur? or... did people simply move on. The policies around interacting with the community are the same today as they were before that post.

Comment: @KevinB great change inside SE, from "Let's kill Meta" to "Let's work with Meta people".

Comment: more like "lets kill meta" to "lets ignore meta but not shout it from the rooftops"

Comment: @KevinB well can't change what you feel, but I really think these days Meta has real effect on SE roadmap. Still not ideal, still lots to improve, but they try, and that's a good thing.

Comment: Hey, I deserve some credit for upvoting this answer _first_, when its score was -1! :D

Comment: @Hcaertnit lol, thanks! Come to Tavern and I'll give you coffee, for free. ;-)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 The irony that one day after you posted this the SE devs destroyed the profile page with no community consultation whatsoever.

Comment: ...in fairness, it wasn't Yaakov.

Comment: @Philippe what wasn't Yaakov? The one who "destroyed the profile page with no community consultation"? I know. curiousdanni's comment isn't really relevant to this answer, but still, the change really really annoyed me, as you might have read in other answer that I posted. (In the "announcement" made by a dev after the change)

Comment: I may choose to interpret this as a circumstance in which staff came to formally respond on Meta, which was a break from the convention at the time, which was welcome. This is only my opinion, but anything *beyond* that feels like a strong Mandela effect.

Comment: @Makoto formally respond implies it followed internal discussion within the company. I don't think there was such a thing in the case I bring in this answer. Yaakov acted on his own.

Comment: I wrote that post on my own initiative. These types of posts were against what was (but thankfully, no longer is) company/department policy at the time, though I did run it informally by a few people (including at least one member of management) before posting it.

Comment: @Makoto see Yaakov comment ^

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to answer this by talking about a type of post rather than a specific one - I love the posts that give our community members the opportunity to show how silly/creative/kind/awesome they can be - sometimes with the incentive of swag but other times just because it's fun to share. These opportunities for users to share a bit of themselves that isn't "strictly business" is something I've really treasured, both my own contributions and reviewing the many contributions of others.

Many of these posts come about as part of our annual Winter Bash event, while others are times where the company wanted to celebrate, such as the 10 year anniversary on Stack Overflow or reaching 10 million questions. Some of these posts are opportunities to showcase talent in a subject or an achievement in their non-Stack Exchange lives. And, well, some of these are my favorite things *I've* done on this site, too, since I've loved sharing a bit about my interest and my creativity on them, too.

#### Winter Bash:

NB: there are tons, so this is a subset

- [Choose your own swag - the craziest contest idea ever! What were we thinking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271359/choose-your-own-swag-the-craziest-contest-idea-ever-what-were-we-thinking)
- [A Moose, Some Silly Putty ... And A Desperate Plea For Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304500/a-moose-some-silly-putty-and-a-desperate-plea-for-help)
- [Winter Bash 2018 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319846/winter-bash-2018-knitting)
- [Announcing Our Amazing 2018 Stuff-A-Way!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321399/announcing-our-amazing-2018-stuff-a-way)
- [Winter Bash 2019 Knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339896/winter-bash-2019-knitting)
- [Show off your hats! (2020 Edition)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357952/show-off-your-hats-2020-edition)

#### Event-based, non Winter Bash

- [10 Million Questions - Let's Share Some Stories That the Number Doesn't Convey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303045/10-million-questions-lets-share-some-stories-that-the-number-doesnt-convey)
- [Time for some more swag!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318910/time-for-some-more-swag)
- [Who cut the cheese?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316515/who-cut-the-cheese)

#### Single-site, community-hosted

- [New Photo Contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7109/new-photo-contest)
- [Screenshot of the Week Contest #44 - RNG](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15962/screenshot-of-the-week-contest-44-rng)
- [Propose future topics for SFF topic challenges!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13240/propose-future-topics-for-sff-topic-challenges)
- [Congratulations: the big thread!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19135/congratulations-the-big-thread)

There are many that I'm certain I'm forgetting, leaving out due to space, or just don't know about but these sorts of posts are, to me, really special.

Answer (score 8):

My favourite post that I've written has to be my [Enigma machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/215387/66833), written in [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), a programming language specifically designed for code golf. (The input format for the one at the top is a bit weird, [here](https://tio.run/##PU9NS8NAEL37M@K1CCoRRMQmqLW1KB4qEoSK4KG1Bw9CURASQQuNClqwVi21jR4EFUJT2U3iZZcW1n8x@0fWiYKnYea9eR/lvUrlSKl5jfUhcqX9uLG0mbOk3WbPQHry9A3o7eQc0FZaYwMRI4F1R20g7rAB9B5oE8hnVTrE4J0dabeGjQV@Z@AvfcdZQknRHN2wAftAdimNO56T09if2/KEdKIqUA9InXmHEF0CORN@YvNiAO0CuYAoQO6@dOLCyiwC/Fr47Gscwvq3CyFlNEGA9hBaPTYPuM9rqIEwhFdA@kC839BlXcQniWIU7G4zzwR6/p8X62nsVTrBenFGT8I/iCdew/JKZbLmorWWy2e2LDWV0lPTSivks9oP)'s an easier way to use it if you want to try it). It took me an entire afternoon to create and was really rewarding to do so. Jelly is a very weird and unintuitive language, especially if you're used to Python, C, Java and similar, and this answer definitely made me feel  like I was much more confident than I used to be with it.

I especially enjoy thinking about how much technology has changed over the years, and I find this answer to be a perfect example of that. 80 years ago, Enigma machines were huge, clunky machines. Now, the entire thing can be represented in fewer bytes than a Tweet (the original, not the new and "improved" ones). In my view, that's a truly crazy level of development.

---

As for my favourite contribution by another user, there's almost too many to choose from. There are countless answers on my main site ([Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)) that are mind-bogglingly impressive ([1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111932/66833), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31863/66833), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/92958/66833), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94829/66833) just to name a few), and I could browse CGCC Meta and MSE for some of the more touching posts about people we trust stepping down and leaving (e.g. [Shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/355458), [Dennis](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18133/66833), and more) which I love simply because their very existence demonstrates just how much people *care* about this network, the sites and their communities.

However, I probably use [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) more than any other part of the network, so I thought I'd choose my favourite message from there, one that always makes me laugh when I look back at it, [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=42578065#42578065), which is just an image:

[image: very smart people. waffles]

Answer (score 8):

[How is y’all’dn’t’ve pronounced](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/312686/106629) is both **my** favourite contribution, and sparked the best responses from **others**. The answers and comments never fail to make me smile when re-read.

Answer (score 8):

I've contributed a LOT of answers on Stack Overflow, but I think some of the content I'm most proud of are some of the **edits**, where I took a complete trainwreck of a question and managed to put myself in the asker's shoes, figure out what they needed, and rewrite the question in a way that actually made sense. Sometimes I even went on to write a valid answer, but not always.

Next in the line would be SQL performance questions. I have a few answers where the OP came back and said via comment my answer took a query that used to run for hours or minutes and reduced it to seconds or milliseconds. The answer wasn't always even that great, in terms of composition, structure, or some finer points of code quality... but when it came down it, it got the job done in a big way.

Answer (score 7):

One of the great unsung stories of Stack would be the chat contribution to PHP development in [the PHP room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php). The craziest story there would be [scalar type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) (PHP 7.0 and later). PHP is an untyped language ([this question on SO deals with what that means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964910/is-javascript-an-untyped-language), albeit for JS, but close enough for the sake of argument), and will gladly coerce variables as needed. There were some who wanted to add strict typing to PHP, but (as is always the problem) there were [competing standards](https://xkcd.com/927/) threatening to derail the whole thing (there were three serious proposals running around at once). And [people were still debating this at the 11th hour](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22072175) for PHP 7.0 features to be added. The winning proposal was on version 5...

[Final vote: 108-48](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5) (needed 67% and got 69%). Still the most voted on RFC in PHP history. Pushed over the finish line, partially due to Stack Chat providing a chat room.

Answer (score 6):

There is a user named [Jon skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

And there is a site called Stack Overflow en español...

And one of the users used to work on Stack Overflow (well, he is working again now... we can't follow him all around all the time!)

And we have a moderator there who is a super fan of his books...

And if this guy can have a selfie 15 meters away of Jon, of course we can have an autograph...

And of course, we want a video saying hi to the community...

And of course, magic happens [here](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3188/324).

Comment: Jon Skeet excels once again, his UK dialect of Spanglish is L1.

Comment: I love this!  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite contribution to Stack Exchange is [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/9161) Perfect constructions in English are really tough for EFL learners to understand and difficult for a typical native English speaker to explain because most of us don’t really think about why we say “I **have** climbed the highest mountains” instead of “I climbed the highest mountains”.

StoneyB broke a giant complex topic into a beautifully written, useful reference full of clear examples and diagrams and essentially donated all of that work to the public. Now if we could just con someone into writing “Canonical Post #3: when to use which article”…

Comment: Oooooh, this is lovely.  My mom taught English, and I just sent this to her.

Comment: The perfect what? xD

Comment: Present perfect is not perfect

Comment: @Philippe I had the song stuck in my head, and I was posting on my phone from work while my simulation was running and not finding what I was looking for…

Answer (score 5):

Ooh, this is a difficult one. So many good posts, in different ways on different sites, over the years. I can't pick out a single favourite contribution, but I can try to make a (short?)list for each of my favourite sites.

- **Science Fiction & Fantasy**

  One of my own answers that I most frequently refer to is [this delicious display of pedantry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90943/31394).

  It's always fun when we get direct responses from authors, actors, directors, or people otherwise actually involved in the topic of the question, and one memorable example was a question about a Star Trek-related legal case that got a [comprehensive answer from the founder of the Language Creation Society](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149965/31394) who was actually involved in the case.

  And of course no list of SFF gems would be complete without mentioning [the most-bountied answer on the SE network](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/105743/31394): in 2011, a former SE employee asked for an ID on a story where the number 3 is the monster, and this became the highest-voted unanswered question on the site, with most of our extremely capable ID experts [taking a crack at it fruitlessly](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7446/31394), before a new user joined the site and became an instant SFF celebrity by successfully answering it (turns out actually the number 5 was the monster).

  Among comments, I'm proud of [this exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/125283/31394) of cross-franchise jokes.
- **Puzzling**

  One of the [most significant questions in the site's history](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/4304/5373) (although not a *good* one, indeed closed as off-topic years ago) was deleted, although it [should've been historical-locked](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6826/5373). It was far too open-ended to work well as an SE puzzle, but it inspired some incredibly lateral thinking, including using an infinite quantity of rope to create a black hole.

  Some of the answers I worked hardest on were [this one about logicians wearing hats](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/10951/5373) and constructing the [world's longest self-documenting sentence](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/17084/5373).

  Puzzling is a unique site in the network, where questions often require more skill and creativity than answers. So it's very hard to choose a favourite question, but although I love the clever word puzzles and tricksy maths puzzles, amazing visual puzzles like [A well balanced puzzle: Logic puzzle(s) in visual disguise](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/6453/5373) and [Red Herring Bonkers In The Red Herring Bunkers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/43714/5373) and [Lepidopterology needed!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/16881/5373) and [Stonehenge - the true purpose](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/55204/5373) have got to take the prize for the "just wow" level of complexity. (I know you didn't ask for favourite *users*, but basically any puzzle by Alconja or Avigrail or Bmyguest will almost certainly be awesome.)

  Among comments, I still laugh about [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15976/me-and-my-gang-again/15983#comment49693_15983) on the futility of hunting internet points.
- **Literature**

  Again, there's so many really detailed and well referenced/explained answers. To name but a few (selected from among my [quarterly best-of](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of) roundups): [Where was the Odyssean Ithaca?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5971/17) and [Where is the start of Treasure Island set?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2329/17) (I'm a sucker for real locations in stories) and [Were English poets of the sixteenth century aware of the Great Vowel Shift?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16449/17) and [Was T. S. Eliot's "The Waste Land" plagiarised?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/9724/17) (two great answers each) and [What is the significance of "southern" in Tagore's poem "A Hundred Years From Now"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16323/17) and [How has knowledge of the Ur-Hamlet evolved over the centuries?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/16889/17) all have incredible above-and-beyond answers.
- **Worldbuilding**

  I'm not active enough there to know which are the best posts. Just check out the whole site, it's amazing. Maybe the best site concept on the whole SE network.

Answer (score 5):

My favourite contribution is [Eliah Kagan](https://askubuntu.com/users/22949/eliah-kagan)'s Q&A about the change to the `sudo` program shipped with Ubuntu from version 19.10 onwards:

[How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10)

Before the change, Ubuntu had shipped a patched version of `sudo` that did something different to the `sudo` on most other Linux distros, such that it was advisable to take precautions when running certain commands with it. The Ask Ubuntu community at large held and reproduced the knowledge that one should not run commands like `sudo graphical-application`, though understanding about why this was so was uneven.

When Ubuntu decided to stop patching `sudo` in an idiosyncratic way and to come back into line with other distros with regard to `sudo`, there was a great need to explain that to our visitors and the Linux world in general, and also to educate the Ask Ubuntu community about the change so that we could provide accurate information and sound advice. A really high quality reference on the topic was required.

Eliah Kagan's post served those purposes, clearly explaining the difference between the old and new `sudo` and the reasons for the change, and also took the opportunity to detail the history of and rationale for Ubuntu's approach. It gathered material from many (and some obscure) sources to bring clarity to a situation that most likely had not previously been understood comprehensively by anyone.

Quote from [a meta post](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16697/527764) also by Eliah Kagan:

> I recommend thinking of Ask Ubuntu as a way to identify things you think should happen in the world and making them happen by doing them: "X should exist. I will make X."

Answer (score 4):

One of the first Q/A pairs I read on Sustainability.SE is this one:

[How effective is turning a car's engine off while standing at a traffic light?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/666/3379)

The accepted answer links some great resources and discussion over on Mechanics.SE, but the thing I really like about it is this: **It gave me practical guidance on how to live more sustainably, the goal of the site!**

Now, whenever I'm in a drive through line, stopped for a train, or at a stoplight that I know (from prior experience) will take a while to change, I switch off my engine. Thanks to this answer, I know that this is the right choice, and helps to reduce my emissions and save my car at once!

---

Oh, and my favorite post of my own has to be [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212670/can-you-please-explain-this-joke-im-going-bananas-is-what-i-tell-my-bananas-b/212674#comment407514_212674) on English Language Learners, a joke that I couldn't believe no one else had made. It's my only contribution to that site, and if it were a post, would be my fifth-most upvoted across the network.

Answer (score 3):

### Best of CGCC<sup>*</sup>

While all of the nominated questions and answers there are amazing, the event itself is one of my favorite things about CGCC. It draws attention to posts by new users, posts that people put a lot of hard work into, posts with insanely clever tricks, and more. Though there are some self-nominations, most of the posts are nominated by other people, and it really shows our spirit of sportmanship.

- [Best of PPCG 2015](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8007/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2015)
- [Best of PPCG 2016](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11186/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2016?rq=1)
- [Best of PPCG 2017](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14614/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2017)
- [Best of PPCG 2018](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17367/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-ppcg-2018)
- [Best of PPCG 2019](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18672/best-of-ppcg-2019-now-accepting-nominations)
- [Best of CGCC 2020](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20638/cast-your-vote-for-best-of-cgcc-2020)

<sup>* The site's name's used to be Programming Puzzles and Code Golf, but changed to Code Golf and Coding Challenges since then.</sup>

Comment: Maybe add a list of links with each year's post?

Answer (score 3):

My favourite contribution from someone else is quite hard to pin down and I’ll have to think about it some more. However, my favourite contribution of my own has to be [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179579/58193) to [Where did Rocket's repair tool come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/179570/58193) about *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol. 2* from SFF. It’s not really from anything I’ve written, which I have many answers I’m proud of, but how often do you get a reply from a director for a major film!?

It was a throwaway tweet made and I came back in the morning to see notifications all over Twitter and [the tweet](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/7sncjn/fun_fact_about_the_repair_tool_in_vol_2/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf) even made it to Reddit and became quite popular there! And thinking about it my tweet, and the question that prompted me to make it, could have even made canon to the film (or just made a fact aware to the audience)! How cool is that!?

So, a bit more unusual in that it isn’t really anything I’ve written myself but certainly my favourite for other reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I think that both my own and others' contribution I'm most proud of is this question of mine and many of its answers:

[Are there any objections to using singular they for everyone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334203/are-there-any-objections-to-using-singular-they-for-everyone)

At the time there was a huge debate over pronouns, and the up and coming CoC. The CoC some people had some knowledge about (moderators etc.), and some people were guessing about what would be in it. It was also around the time of a moderator being removed, and tempers, emotions and posts were flying around heated.

At that time I proposed to just "be done with it" and why not use only one pronoun. Now admittedly that wasn't a great solution, as it didn't fix the problem. As some people would/could be offended by using that pronoun, and as it was too hard for other to wrap their head around. But what makes me proud of this post is that amidst all the heated debate we had a (mostly) civilised discussion. (I can't see deleted comments ofcourse.) People brought arguments forward on why my proposed solution wasn't right and there was next to no swearing and shouting involved.

Answer (score 3):

My all-time favorite contributions are probably these two community wiki self-answer style questions/answers by [John Rennie](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1325/john-rennie) on [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/):

- [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/)
- [What is time, does it flow, and if so what defines its direction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235511/)

As someone aspiring to be a physicist but has not yet a very detailed understanding of the concepts, it amazes me how these answers are simple (in that they are understandable without many prerequisites), but detailed at the same time. Both of these answers have cleared some misconceptions for me and are very useful to link in comments :)

For my own contributions, the one that I am most "proud" of is probably [Visualizing wormholes without embedding spacetime](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/639451/) – probably because of the many hours of confusion and research that went into this question.

My most upvoted post though is [my answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/607561/) to [What do atomic orbitals represent in quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/607552/).

---

Also, if it counts, the [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/) has been extremely helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> - Do you have a favourite contribution that **someone else** added?  What is it?  Why do you like it?

My favourite contribution is this [Question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/66104/105447) / [Answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/66105/105447) by [Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1737/gayot-fow).

There are several reasons I like it:

- First of all, it's a self-answered question and whilst these aren't popular and some users find it hard to self-answer their own questions or even think that this isn't allowed, it proves that self-answered questions can be very successful
- Secondly, I like how comprehensive the answer is and how it has an extensive list of FAQ's and serves as a complete FAQ for bank statements when applying for a UK visa and can be used to close most if not all questions relating to bank statements when applying for a UK visa
- Thirdly, I like the diagrams that the answer includes to provide a visual representation to complement the text and are an excellent asset for people who prefer [visual learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_learning) (like myself)

Answer (score 2):

This one's easy for me: this answer I wrote. (4000 upvotes now, whee...)

**[How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/263268)**

What a journey of discovery into the depths of just how crazy YAML syntax is, and how deluded is everyone who thinks it is "simple".

It's nice getting the comments from people occasionally about how this helped them, and it even inspired someone to make a website: http://yaml-multiline.info/

(I kind of wish I could turn off all the upvote notifications though, they get spammy.)

Answer (score 2):

Over on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/), it's hard to find objective questions that haven't been extensively answered elsewhere on the internet, so I'm partial to answers that display a great deal of effort and research by the answerer, especially for situations that don't come up all that often but are interesting to know about nonetheless.

As such, one of my favourite answers has to be [this one about the order EVs are awarded in Pokémon Sapphire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302050/143571). The question is laregely theoretical in nature and not particularly important for players, since you can always avoid putting yourself in a scenario where such knowledge is needed, but the answer is so thorough and methodical that I can't help but be impressed.

Of my own contributions, my favourite has to be [this list of rare endemic life in Monster Hunter World](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/345948/143571). Before starting this list, all information I could find was scattered and incomplete, and in some cases outright wrong. It is now the most comprehensive such list I'm aware of, having evolved over the span of several months and counting (at the moment) 145 revisions and 264 images. It has been a huge effort of finding resources online, confirming them in game with screenshots, understanding the rules of how these critters spawn, and lots of my own findings that I've never seen mentioned before.

Comment: I don't know if it would be "the best of Stack" or "the worst of Stack", but some of those Arqade question titles are rather...odd...when taken out of context.

Answer (score 1):

> - Do you have a favorite contribution that someone else added? What is it? Why do you like it?

This one [How do I use installed packages in PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19885821)

There are 2 reasons why I like this question:

1. I love using Python libraries/packages in PyCharm so the entire concept is beautiful.
2. I close at least one question every day using this post as a duplicate target. Without such canonical posts SO would be a research nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to pick favourites from over 10 years of network history. I have seen so many great questions and answers from other people and also myself written so many posts I'm very proud of over the years, that this question seems almost impossible to answer, especially since all those posts are extremely different and uncomparable. However, I'll try to pick something broader pertaining to things about the SE network and specifically my usual home site of [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) that make it stand out on the internet.

---

As to my own contributions, I would generally list [my answers about *Interstellar*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:49%20%5Binterstellar%5D%20is:answer), not necessarily because these answers are so great or the best I've written (though, some of them I am indeed proud of above average, but maybe not all of them), but because the period when most of these questions were asked and answered for me marked not only the most productive period since the earliest days of the site but also **the pinnacle of what the site's manifesto is talking about when it speaks of "...contributing to the appreciation of the film...".**

Now the film sure impressed me a lot and that is certainly a subjective thing. But what really kept me engaged to it for weeks was that very site and its **questions that furthered my delving deeper into some aspects of the film and related materials**, driving me to answer some of the questions arising about it. And a lot of the questions were indeed really great too, it's not just that I like my answers to them. I even spent a good portion of a sunday evening trying to write my single only [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) answer.

And that is what the site is able to do, furthering the discussion of the things that move us, be that by posing engaging questions or writing interesting answers. It provides a platform to not only **find and enjoy interesting information but also delight in writing about the stuff you care about yourself. And that all while hopefully "making the internet a better place"** by filling it with useful information. (Also notice how I said "discussion", a word sometimes eschewed on SE when taken too literal. But it is this formalized and well-structured way of discussing things that the Q&A format enables so well.)

---

As to the contributions of others, the above mentioned problems with comparing and pinning down an exact best over all those years make this really difficult. So forgive me when again using another post of mine to point to another amazing aspect of the SE format. I am very partial to [sanpaco's answer to a question of mine](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92170/49) about a rather underrated film (Peter Weir's *The Way Back*, to be precise). You'll notice the question is about 4.5 years older than the answer. But not only was it a late answer, I had actually almost given up on the question. I already half answered it in the question and it also at some point got auto-deleted for inactivity.

But not only does it receive an **answer almost 5 years later**, it even gets an answer **that provides entirely new insights I hadn't ever considered** when having seen the movie a few times again since asking the question. It again absolutely "contributed to my appreciation of the film", but even more so it also showed that **a question on SE is never really dead**. Now fortunately our site's topic tends to be one where we can usually afford some patience for a good answer and as long as we have that, **any time someone else might come around who does not only share your interest but who has the answer you've been waiting for for years**.

Answer (score 1):

There are heaps of great contributions out there but my favourite ones are the following (most of them are written by [Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/47827/janus-bahs-jacquet)):

- [The pronunciation of the word 'junta'](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/491099/365490)
- [Why do people often say 'hambag' for 'handbag'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/199170/365490)
- [What does the word “wind” mean in this John Donne poem?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/362861/365490)
- [What is the pronunciation of “ttiwdty”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/210236/365490)

and finally [Why is the W silent in “sword” but not in “swore”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/266296/106592) (I wrote it myself on ELL)